# Create a Pandas Dataframe by appending one row at a time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

How do I create an empty `DataFrame`, then add rows, one by one?

I created an empty `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('lib', 'qty1', 'qty2'))
```

Then I can add a new row at the end and fill a single field with:

```
df = df._set_value(index=len(df), col='qty1', value=10.0)
```

It works for only one field at a time. What is a better way to add new row to `df`?

Comment: Note this is a very inefficient way to build a large DataFrame; new arrays have to be created (copying over the existing data) when you append a row.

Comment: @WesMcKinney: Thx, that's really good to know. Is it very fast to add *columns* to huge tables?

Comment: If it is too inefficient for you, you may preallocate an additional row and then update it.

Comment: Hey you... yes, **you**... I see what you're up to... you want to run this inside a loop and iteratively add rows to an empty DataFrame, don't you... well, [don't!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56746204/4909087)

Comment: I might understand this can be in general wrong but, what about real-time processing? So say I have some data that comes in every second and I have a thread that just wants to fill a dataframe and have another even-based thread that goes and look at the dataframe? I find this use case valid and where that solution is applicable to

Comment: @Giuseppe then pandas DataFrame is not the right data structure, since it's designed for analysis, not for real-time processing.

Comment: Thanks @justhalf, I guess it's because of the way it is implemented it won't be suitable for such kind of scenarios. Digging around I found this https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/10/16/streaming-dataframes-1 , I am not sure if it's the right solution but I will surely give it a shot

Comment: Great news @cs95, Pandas has officially deprecated the ```append``` method ! https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Comment: @Heartthrob_Rob, cs95 There are a lot of pandas answers here using append() method!. What we have to do with that? advice? Flag? Votedown? Reanswer?.

Comment: @rubengavidia0x Now that ```append()``` is deprecated, IMO best practice here would be to iteratively add to a list/dict/array/etc. and when completed, subsequently assign this to a dataframe (either creating a new one or concatenating). Something like Brian's response below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46729742/11790080)

Comment: @rubengavidia0x editing all answers that include `append` and mentioning the deprecation is the most effective way to alert readers to this. Downvoting also appears sensible if people think the minor benefit this brings is worth their time & reputation.

Comment: @rubengavidia0x add a note on the outdated answers that append is now deprecated and link to updated docs and answers. Btw, I have updated my answer to include this gem of a tidbit.

Answer (score 908, accepted):

You can use `df.loc[i]`, where the row with index `i` will be what you specify it to be in the dataframe.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from numpy.random import randint

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['lib', 'qty1', 'qty2'])
>>> for i in range(5):
>>>     df.loc[i] = ['name' + str(i)] + list(randint(10, size=2))

>>> df
     lib qty1 qty2
0  name0    3    3
1  name1    2    4
2  name2    2    8
3  name3    2    1
4  name4    9    6
```

Comment: Consider adding the index to preallocate memory (see my answer)

Comment: `.loc` is referencing the index column, so if you're working with a pre-existing DataFrame with an index that isn't a continous sequence of integers starting with 0 (as in your example), `.loc` will overwrite existing rows, or insert rows, or create gaps in your index. A more robust (but not fool-proof) approach for appending an existing nonzero-length dataframe would be: `df.loc[df.index.max() + 1] = [randint(...` or prepopulating the index as @FooBar suggested.

Comment: @hobs `df.index.max()` is `nan` when the DataFrame is empty.

Comment: @flow2k good catch! Only solution I can think of is a try accept (on the first row insertion only) with a pd.DataFrame() constructor call. Do you know any better ways?

Comment: @hobs One solution I thought of is using the ternary operator: `df.loc[0 if pd.isnull(df.index.max()) else df.index.max() + 1]`

Comment: `df.loc[i, "column_name"] = new_value` will also fill in a specific field, if you just need to pad out the last value of a column so that another operation will carry through (eg. for plotting a `.cumsum()`)

Comment: df.loc[len(df.index)] = row

Comment: Is `loc[]` still the best way to do this?

Comment: Why does this NOT work with a multiindex: `df.loc[(2,4),:] = [4,5]`  gives a "not in index" error when starting with an empty DataFrame.

Answer (score 797):

In case you can get all data for the data frame upfront, there is a much faster approach than appending to a data frame:

1. Create a list of dictionaries in which each dictionary corresponds to an input data row.
2. Create a data frame from this list.

I had a similar task for which appending to a data frame row by row took 30 min, and creating a data frame from a list of dictionaries completed within seconds.

```
rows_list = []
for row in input_rows:
    dict1 = {}
    # get input row in dictionary format
    # key = col_name
    dict1.update(blah..) 

    rows_list.append(dict1)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
```

Comment: I've moved to doing this as well for any situation where I can't get all the data up front. The speed difference is astonishing.

Comment: Copying from pandas docs:                                                                          `It is worth noting however, that concat (and therefore append) makes a full copy of the data, and that constantly reusing this function can create a significant performance hit. If you need to use the operation over several datasets, use a list comprehension.` (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects)

Comment: This works great! Except when I created the data frame, the columns names were all in the wrong order...

Comment: @user5359531  You can use ordered dict in that case

Comment: @user5359531 You can manually specify the columns and the order will be preserved. 

pd.DataFrame(rows_list, columns=['C1', 'C2','C3']) will do the trick

Comment: @ShikharDua Can you explain how to structure the data, i.e. when you say # get input row in dictionary format
        # key = col_name
what do you mean? my use case: I am fetching rows from a MySQL table and each `row` object is coming as a tuple containing 10 strings

Comment: @avg I am guessing each tuple is supposed to be a row in pandas table. In that case, it can be an element if the row_list instead of dict1. And once all data is on form of [tuple1, tuple2, tuple 3, .....] then you can create a final dataset

Comment: @avg, it's probably better to use the [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) method in that case. Then you don't have to worry about parsing it on your own.

Comment: What is the performance difference between a list of dicts (1 dict per row) and 1 dict with each value a list? (1 list per col)

Comment: I tried this in my code using Tuple and it is even faster than Dict. 3 times faster for 160 rows and 4 columns in my case.

Comment: @thikonom Isn't the append function used here a Python list (not a pandas object), which has [O(1) amortized append() in CPython](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)?  This answer looks good to me.

Comment: Why are we using dict.update() rather than subscripting as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456158/python-dict-update-vs-subscript-to-add-a-single-key-value-pair)?

Comment: @the775 you can use whatever you want.

Comment: @ShikharDua appreciate it. I mentioned it because the article I [tagged above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456158/python-dict-update-vs-subscript-to-add-a-single-key-value-pair) mentions the runtime of the native `dict1[key] = value` is faster than the .update() method, and many of the answers are concerned with speed.

Comment: is this the way to do it for an existing dataframe by transposing the dataframe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29815523/13865853

Comment: actually isn't it faster doing `df_dict = df.to_dict('records')` ?  This way you get dictionaries with column names, not an int for column number as keys.

Comment: Maybe it's my problem, but I can't understand the solution from the code. Could you make it more explicit?

Comment: U can also use CSV writer directly and wont even need pandas for dumping data to csv file

Answer (score 445):

In the case of adding a lot of rows to dataframe, I am interested **in performance**. So I tried the four most popular methods and checked their speed.

### **Performance**

1. Using .append ([NPE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10716007/4960953))
2. Using .loc ([fred's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24888331/4960953))
3. Using .loc with preallocating ([FooBar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24913075/4960953))
4. Using dict and create DataFrame in the end ([ShikharDua's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17496530/4960953))

**Runtime results (in seconds):**

| Approach | 1000 rows | 5000 rows | 10 000 rows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .append | 0.69 | 3.39 | 6.78 |
| .loc without prealloc | 0.74 | 3.90 | 8.35 |
| .loc with prealloc | 0.24 | 2.58 | 8.70 |
| dict | 0.012 | 0.046 | 0.084 |

So I use addition through the dictionary for myself.

---

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

del df1, df2, df3, df4
numOfRows = 1000
# append
startTime = time.perf_counter()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(5,5)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
for i in range( 1,numOfRows-4):
    df1 = df1.append( dict( (a,np.random.randint(100)) for a in ['A','B','C','D','E']), ignore_index=True)
print('Elapsed time: {:6.3f} seconds for {:d} rows'.format(time.perf_counter() - startTime, numOfRows))
print(df1.shape)

# .loc w/o prealloc
startTime = time.perf_counter()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(5,5)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
for i in range( 1,numOfRows):
    df2.loc[i]  = np.random.randint(100, size=(1,5))[0]
print('Elapsed time: {:6.3f} seconds for {:d} rows'.format(time.perf_counter() - startTime, numOfRows))
print(df2.shape)

# .loc with prealloc
df3 = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, numOfRows), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] )
startTime = time.perf_counter()
for i in range( 1,numOfRows):
    df3.loc[i]  = np.random.randint(100, size=(1,5))[0]
print('Elapsed time: {:6.3f} seconds for {:d} rows'.format(time.perf_counter() - startTime, numOfRows))
print(df3.shape)

# dict
startTime = time.perf_counter()
row_list = []
for i in range (0,5):
    row_list.append(dict( (a,np.random.randint(100)) for a in ['A','B','C','D','E']))
for i in range( 1,numOfRows-4):
    dict1 = dict( (a,np.random.randint(100)) for a in ['A','B','C','D','E'])
    row_list.append(dict1)

df4 = pd.DataFrame(row_list, columns=['A','B','C','D','E'])
print('Elapsed time: {:6.3f} seconds for {:d} rows'.format(time.perf_counter() - startTime, numOfRows))
print(df4.shape)
```

P.S.: I believe my realization isn't perfect, and maybe there is some optimization that could be done.

Comment: The use of `df2.index.max()` for `.loc` needlessly increases computational complexity.  Simple `df2.loc[i] = ...` would do. For me it reduced the time from 10s to 8.64s

Comment: Please remove my name from the list, since you're not following my approach in your test: You're not preallocating the memory by providing an index of suitable size.

Comment: @FooBar Hi! I'm glad you as the author saw my answer :) you are right, I missed this important point. I prefer to add one more row for my result table as your approach show the different  result!

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam How would you use pivot-table to write it on an excel file using the fastest method, dict ?

Comment: Why use a list of dicts instead of just hstacking the numpy into a 2D array, and converting  and adding column names at the end?

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti in the dict-methods we get df at the ens. So as in the all other methods. So there is no any problem to create [pivot-table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) on it. Here, for example, you can find example of reading/writing to Excel: [pivot-tables on Excel](https://pbpython.com/pandas-pivot-report.html)

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam For the last, dict approach, what's the rationale behind using two loops, `for i in range (0,5):` and `for i in range( 1,numOfRows-4):`?

Comment: Just wanted to throw out another comment as to why the Dict to Pandas DataFrame is a better way.  In my experimentation with a dataset that has multiple different data types in the table, using the Pandas append methods destroy the typing, whereas using a Dict, and only creating the DataFrame from it ONCE, seems to keep the original datatypes intact.

Comment: I have a different method which should be comparable to dictionary method but could be marginally faster that you should try timing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59524806/3163618

Comment: I tested it and it is slightly faster: list-of-dicts: 1000:0.034, 5000:0.155, 10000:0.342. dict-of-lists: 1000:0.032, 5000:0.149, 10000:0.295

Comment: I tried this in my code using Tuple and it is even faster than Dict. Just wondering that Tuple are immutable. So how are we able to append them ?

Comment: @rayzinnz I have not tried, but I suppose it should not be faster - numpy arrays are contiguous pieces of memory, so numpy recreates the array every time you use htack. While the list just add a pointer to a new variable in another memory location.

Comment: I think the `dict` approach should be renamed the `list.append` approach (and `append` into `df.append`), it is faster because it relies on a list `row_list.append()` and then creates a dataframe from that list instead of appending data directly on the dataframe with `df1.append()`. Both methods use dictionaries, the point is using `list()` vs `pd.DataFrame()` when populating data row by row.

Comment: You should also use `timeit.timeit` for micro-benchmarks to avoid some common benchmarking issues.

Answer (score 356):

You could use `pandas.concat()`. For details and examples, see [Merge, join, and concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

For example:

```
def append_row(df, row):
    return pd.concat([
                df, 
                pd.DataFrame([row], columns=row.index)]
           ).reset_index(drop=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('lib', 'qty1', 'qty2'))
new_row = pd.Series({'lib':'A', 'qty1':1, 'qty2': 2})

df = append_row(df, new_row)
```

Comment: Hi, so what is the answer for the methods using append() or concat(). I have the same problem, but still trying to figuring it out.

Comment: This is the right answer, but it isn't a very *good* answer (almost link only).

Comment: I think @fred's answer is more correct.  IIUC the problem with this answer is that it needlessly copies the entire DataFrame every time a row is appended.  Using the `.loc` mechanism that can be avoided, especially if you're careful.

Comment: But if you want to use `DataFrame.append()`, you have to make sure your row data is also a DataFrame in the first place, not a list.

Comment: DataFrame.append() is [deprecated since version 1.4.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append), use only pandas.concat() in future like pandas.concat([DF1, DF2])

Answer (score 316):

## from pandas >= 2.0, `append` has been removed!

`DataFrame.append` was deprecated in version 1.4 and removed from the pandas API entirely in version 2.0.

See the docs on [Deprecations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#deprecations) as well as [this github issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGIV6.png) that originally proposed its deprecation.

If you are running pandas version 2.0 or later, you will likely run into the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append' for DataFrame
```

Keep reading if you would like to learn about more idiomatic alternatives to `append`.

---

## NEVER grow a DataFrame!

Yes, people have already explained that you should NEVER grow a DataFrame, and that you should append your data to a list and convert it to a DataFrame once at the end. But do you understand why?

Here are the most important reasons, taken from my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56746204/4909087).

1. It is always cheaper/faster to append to a list and create a DataFrame in one go.
2. Lists take up less memory and are a much lighter data structure to work with, append, and remove.
3. `dtypes` are automatically inferred for your data. On the flip side, creating an empty frame of NaNs will automatically make them `object`, which is bad.
4. An index is automatically created for you, instead of you having to take care to assign the correct index to the row you are appending.

---

### This is The Right Way™ to accumulate your data

```
data = []
for a, b, c in some_function_that_yields_data():
    data.append([a, b, c])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Note that if `some_function_that_yields_data()` returns smaller DataFrames, you can accumulate individual DataFrames inside a list and then make a single call to [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) at the end.

### These options are horrible

1. **`append` or `concat` inside a loop**

   `append` and `concat` aren't inherently bad **in isolation**. The
   problem starts when you iteratively call them inside a loop - this
   results in quadratic memory usage.

   ```
   # Creates empty DataFrame and appends
   df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
   for a, b, c in some_function_that_yields_data():
       df = df.append({'A': i, 'B': b, 'C': c}, ignore_index=True)  
       # This is equally bad:
       # df = pd.concat(
       #       [df, pd.Series({'A': i, 'B': b, 'C': c})], 
       #       ignore_index=True)
   ```
2. **Empty DataFrame of NaNs**

   Never create a DataFrame of NaNs as the columns are initialized with
   `object` (slow, un-vectorizable dtype).

   ```
   # Creates DataFrame of NaNs and overwrites values.
   df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=range(5))
   for a, b, c in some_function_that_yields_data():
       df.loc[len(df)] = [a, b, c]
   ```

### The Proof is in the Pudding

Timing these methods is the fastest way to see just how much they differ in terms of their memory and utility.

[image]

[Benchmarking code for reference.](https://gist.github.com/Coldsp33d/ea080f580ab3a3b75c2f40c201d50164)

---

It's posts like this that remind me why I'm a part of this community. People understand the importance of teaching folks getting the right answer with the *right* code, not the right answer with *wrong* code. Now you might argue that it is not an issue to use `loc` or `append` if you're only adding a single row to your DataFrame. However, **people often look to this question to add more than just *one* row** - often the requirement is to iteratively add a row inside a loop using data that comes from a function (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13784192/4909087)). In that case it is important to understand that iteratively growing a DataFrame is not a good idea.

Comment: Fair enough. Are there any solution in case you need (or would like) a dataframe, but all your samples really do come one after the other? (Typically online learning or active learning)

Comment: This doesn't factor in the case where one needs the dataframe after every append(). In that case, the dataframe gets copied anyway, so the df.loc method is faster

Comment: @DevAggarwal incorrect, loc also creates a copy each time. Please see the graph timings in my answer. Append and loc_append are equally bad. I've also shared my code and process so you're free to convince yourself.

Comment: Aplogies should have been clearer. Kindly create the dataframe from intermediate list inside the for loop, here -- https://gist.github.com/Coldsp33d/ea080f580ab3a3b75c2f40c201d50164#file-create_df-py-L13

Comment: Has anyone benchmarked what @DevAggarwal suggests? I often get to that case

Comment: @Kuzeko the graph in my answer shows they are about the same in terms of performance, equally bad and so I wouldn't particularly recommend one over the other. If your case requires the Dataframe at each iteration, perhaps you should consider rethinking the structure of your code. Maybe use map or apply.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.  I made a small benchmark adapting your code to my data and it still seems better the list append method, even though advantage is reduced. Unfortunately I need to pass it to third party libraries, so I need to create that dataframe.

Comment: well, most dataframe is supper big and can not be stored in RAM, so it is still good to grow it if you have dataframe store on a disk such as HDFStore etc.

Comment: list append vs dict?

Comment: how if the data come from another dataframe?

Answer (score 133):

If you know the number of entries ex ante, you should preallocate the space by also providing the index (taking the data example from a different answer):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# we know we're gonna have 5 rows of data
numberOfRows = 5
# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, numberOfRows), columns=('lib', 'qty1', 'qty2') )

# now fill it up row by row
for x in np.arange(0, numberOfRows):
    #loc or iloc both work here since the index is natural numbers
    df.loc[x] = [np.random.randint(-1,1) for n in range(3)]
In[23]: df
Out[23]: 
   lib  qty1  qty2
0   -1    -1    -1
1    0     0     0
2   -1     0    -1
3    0    -1     0
4   -1     0     0
```

**Speed comparison**

```
In[30]: %timeit tryThis() # function wrapper for this answer
In[31]: %timeit tryOther() # function wrapper without index (see, for example, @fred)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.31 ms per loop
```

And - as from the comments - with a size of 6000, the speed difference becomes even larger:

> Increasing the size of the array (12) and the number of rows (500) makes
>   the speed difference more striking: 313ms vs 2.29s

Comment: Great answer. This should be the norm so that row space doesn't have to allocated incrementally.

Comment: Increasing the size of the array(12) and the number of rows(500) makes the speed difference more striking: 313ms vs 2.29s

Answer (score 94):

```
mycolumns = ['A', 'B']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=mycolumns)
rows = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
for row in rows:
    df.loc[len(df)] = row
```

Comment: This! I've been searching for quite a while, and this is the first post that really shows how to assign particular values to a row! Bonus question: Which is the syntax for column-name/value pairs? I guess it must be something using a dict, but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: this is not efficient as it actually copies the entire DataFrame when you extend it.

Comment: consider doing `len(df.index)` instead.

Answer (score 81):

You can append a single row as a dictionary using the `ignore_index` option.

```
>>> f = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'Animal':['cow','horse'], 'Color':['blue', 'red']})
>>> f
  Animal Color
0    cow  blue
1  horse   red
>>> f.append({'Animal':'mouse', 'Color':'black'}, ignore_index=True)
  Animal  Color
0    cow   blue
1  horse    red
2  mouse  black
```

Comment: You might also mention that `f.append(<stuff>)` creates a new object, rather than simply appending to the current object in place, so if you're trying to append to a dataframe in a script, you need to say `f = f.append(<stuff>)`

Comment: is there a way to do this in place?

Comment: @lol no. see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2801 - the underlying arrays can't be extended so they have to be copied.

Comment: I prefer this method because it is very SQL-like (not dependent on indices semantically) and I use it whenever possible.

Answer (score 79):

For efficient appending, see *[How to add an extra row to a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365513/how-to-add-an-extra-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe/19368360#19368360)* and [*Setting With Enlargement*](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement).

Add rows through `loc/ix` on **non existing** key index data. For example:

```
In [1]: se = pd.Series([1,2,3])

In [2]: se
Out[2]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64

In [3]: se[5] = 5.

In [4]: se
Out[4]:
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
5    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Or:

```
In [1]: dfi = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3,2),
   .....:                 columns=['A','B'])
   .....:

In [2]: dfi
Out[2]:
   A  B
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5

In [3]: dfi.loc[:,'C'] = dfi.loc[:,'A']

In [4]: dfi
Out[4]:
   A  B  C
0  0  1  0
1  2  3  2
2  4  5  4
In [5]: dfi.loc[3] = 5

In [6]: dfi
Out[6]:
   A  B  C
0  0  1  0
1  2  3  2
2  4  5  4
3  5  5  5
```

Comment: The users asked for implement (add a new row). Here we see how to add a row in a defined index or add a column.

Comment: any benchmarks on how this works out compared to the dict method

Comment: this is not efficient as it actually copies the entire DataFrame.

Answer (score 48):

For the sake of a Pythonic way:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(columns=('lib', 'qty1', 'qty2'))
res = res.append([{'qty1':10.0}], ignore_index=True)
print(res.head())

   lib  qty1  qty2
0  NaN  10.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 38):

You can also build up a list of lists and convert it to a dataframe -

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['i','double','square']
rows = []

for i in range(6):
    row = [i, i*2, i*i]
    rows.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
```

giving

```
    i   double  square
0   0   0   0
1   1   2   1
2   2   4   4
3   3   6   9
4   4   8   16
5   5   10  25
```

Answer (score 22):

If you always want to add a new row at the end, use this:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = ['name5', 9, 0]
```

Comment: This presumes that the index of the dataframe is numbered AND that it is perfectly sequential. Using `df.reset_index()` could resolve this, but as it stands it may actually overwrite an existing row.

Answer (score 18):

I figured out a simple and nice way:

```
>>> df
     A  B  C
one  1  2  3
>>> df.loc["two"] = [4,5,6]
>>> df
     A  B  C
one  1  2  3
two  4  5  6
```

Note the caveat with performance as noted in the comments.

Comment: Note that this will copy the entire DataFrame under the hood. The underlying arrays can't be extended so they have to be copied.

Answer (score 17):

Instead of a list of dictionaries as in [ShikharDua's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/create-a-pandas-dataframe-by-appending-one-row-at-a-time/17496530#17496530) (row-based), we can also represent our table as a **dictionary of lists** (column-based), where each list stores one column (in row-order), given we know our columns beforehand. At the end we construct our DataFrame *once*.

In both cases, the dictionary keys are always the column names. Row order is stored implicitly as order in a list. For *c* columns and *n* rows, this uses one dictionary of *c* lists (of length *n*), versus one list of *n* dictionaries (with *c* entries). The list-of-dictionaries method has each dictionary storing all keys redundantly and requires creating a new dictionary for every row. Here we only append to lists, which overall is the same time complexity (adding entries to list and dictionary are both amortized constant time) but may have less time and space overhead due to lists being simpler than dictionaries.

```
# Current data
data = {"Animal":["cow", "horse"], "Color":["blue", "red"]}

# Adding a new row (be careful to ensure every column gets another value)
data["Animal"].append("mouse")
data["Color"].append("black")

# At the end, construct our DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#   Animal  Color
# 0    cow   blue
# 1  horse    red
# 2  mouse  black
```

Comment: I found this method to be the most convenient to use, as you never have to worry about column order when appending new values.

Answer (score 14):

This is not an answer to the OP question, but a toy example to illustrate [ShikharDua's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/create-a-pandas-dataframe-by-appending-one-row-at-a-time/17496530#17496530) which I found very useful.

While this fragment is trivial, in the actual data I had 1,000s of rows, and many columns, and I wished to be able to group by different columns and then perform the statistics below for more than one target column. So having a reliable method for building the data frame one row at a time was a great convenience. Thank you ShikharDua!

```
import pandas as pd

BaseData = pd.DataFrame({ 'Customer' : ['Acme','Mega','Acme','Acme','Mega','Acme'],
                          'Territory'  : ['West','East','South','West','East','South'],
                          'Product'  : ['Econ','Luxe','Econ','Std','Std','Econ']})
BaseData

columns = ['Customer','Num Unique Products', 'List Unique Products']

rows_list=[]
for name, group in BaseData.groupby('Customer'):
    RecordtoAdd={} #initialise an empty dict
    RecordtoAdd.update({'Customer' : name}) #
    RecordtoAdd.update({'Num Unique Products' : len(pd.unique(group['Product']))})
    RecordtoAdd.update({'List Unique Products' : pd.unique(group['Product'])})

    rows_list.append(RecordtoAdd)

AnalysedData = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)

print('Base Data : \n',BaseData,'\n\n Analysed Data : \n',AnalysedData)
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use a generator object to create a Dataframe, which will be more memory efficient over the list.

```
num = 10

# Generator function to generate generator object
def numgen_func(num):
    for i in range(num):
        yield ('name_{}'.format(i), (i*i), (i*i*i))

# Generator expression to generate generator object (Only once data get populated, can not be re used)
numgen_expression = (('name_{}'.format(i), (i*i), (i*i*i)) for i in range(num) )

df = pd.DataFrame(data=numgen_func(num), columns=('lib', 'qty1', 'qty2'))
```

To add raw to existing DataFrame you can use append method.

```
df = df.append([{ 'lib': "name_20", 'qty1': 20, 'qty2': 400  }])
```

Answer (score 9):

Create a **new record (data frame)** and add to **old_data_frame**.

Pass a list of **values** and the corresponding **column** names to create a **new_record** (data_frame):

```
new_record = pd.DataFrame([[0, 'abcd', 0, 1, 123]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

old_data_frame = pd.concat([old_data_frame, new_record])
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is the way to add/append a row in a Pandas `DataFrame`:

```
def add_row(df, row):
    df.loc[-1] = row
    df.index = df.index + 1
    return df.sort_index()

add_row(df, [1,2,3])
```

It can be used to insert/append a row in an empty or populated Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: this is adding with index in descending order

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add a row at the end, append it as a list:

```
valuestoappend = [va1, val2, val3]
res = res.append(pd.Series(valuestoappend, index = ['lib', 'qty1', 'qty2']), ignore_index = True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it (probably not very performant):

```
# add a row
def add_row(df, row):
    colnames = list(df.columns)
    ncol = len(colnames)
    assert ncol == len(row), "Length of row must be the same as width of DataFrame: %s" % row
    return df.append(pd.DataFrame([row], columns=colnames))
```

You can also enhance the DataFrame class like this:

```
import pandas as pd
def add_row(self, row):
    self.loc[len(self.index)] = row
pd.DataFrame.add_row = add_row
```

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate two DataFrames for this. I basically came across this problem to add a new row to an existing DataFrame with a character index (not numeric).

So, I input the data for a new row in a duct() and index in a list.

```
new_dict = {put input for new row here}
new_list = [put your index here]

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=new_dict, index=new_list)

df = pd.concat([existing_df, new_df])
```

Comment: this is literally what I need

Answer (score 3):

All you need is `loc[df.shape[0]]` or `loc[len(df)]`

---

```
# Assuming your df has 4 columns (str, int, str, bool)
df.loc[df.shape[0]] = ['col1Value', 100, 'col3Value', False]
```

or

```
df.loc[len(df)] = ['col1Value', 100, 'col3Value', False]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
initial_data = {'lib': np.array([1,2,3,4]), 'qty1': [1,2,3,4], 'qty2': [1,2,3,4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(initial_data)

df

lib    qty1    qty2
0    1    1    1
1    2    2    2
2    3    3    3
3    4    4    4

val_1 = [10]
val_2 = [14]
val_3 = [20]

df.append(pd.DataFrame({'lib': val_1, 'qty1': val_2, 'qty2': val_3}))

lib    qty1    qty2
0    1    1    1
1    2    2    2
2    3    3    3
3    4    4    4
0    10    14    20
```

You can use a *for* loop to iterate through values or can add arrays of values.

```
val_1 = [10, 11, 12, 13]
val_2 = [14, 15, 16, 17]
val_3 = [20, 21, 22, 43]

df.append(pd.DataFrame({'lib': val_1, 'qty1': val_2, 'qty2': val_3}))

lib    qty1    qty2
0    1    1    1
1    2    2    2
2    3    3    3
3    4    4    4
0    10    14    20
1    11    15    21
2    12    16    22
3    13    17    43
```

Comment: An explanation for the first part would be in order. And why isn't there a "for" loop in the example code when it is talked about? Can you make it more clear? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62361637/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple. By taking a list as input which will be appended as a row in the data-frame:

```
import pandas as pd
res = pd.DataFrame(columns=('lib', 'qty1', 'qty2'))
for i in range(5):
    res_list = list(map(int, input().split()))
    res = res.append(pd.Series(res_list, index=['lib', 'qty1', 'qty2']), ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

We often see the construct `df.loc[subscript] = …` to assign to one DataFrame row. [Mikhail_Sam posted benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47979665/2413201) containing, among others, this construct as well as the method using *dict and create DataFrame in the end*. He found the latter to be the fastest by far.

But if we replace the `df3.loc[i]  = …` (with preallocated DataFrame) in his code with `df3.values[i] = …`, the outcome changes significantly, in that that method performs similar to the one using dict. So we should more often take the use of `df.values[subscript] = …` into consideration. However note that `.values` takes a zero-based subscript, which may be different from the DataFrame.index.

Comment: @baxx - One _code example_ is at the _benchmarks_ link (`# .loc with prealloc`), another example is in the question [I have to compare data from each row of a Pandas DataFrame with data from the rest of the rows, is there a way to speed up the computation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572695/i-have-to-compare-data-from-each-row-of-a-pandas-dataframe-with-data-from-the-re) and its accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

pandas.DataFrame.append

DataFrame.append(self, other, ignore_index=False, verify_integrity=False, sort=False) → 'DataFrame'

#### Code

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))
df.append(df2)
```

With ignore_index set to True:

```
df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: It is not clear why the first two lines are not literal code. Brevity is good, but can you [elaborate in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60294358/edit), e.g. by adding some supporting text? But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Answer (score 0):

Before going to add a row, we have to convert the dataframe to a dictionary. There you can see the keys as columns in the dataframe and the values of the columns are again stored in the dictionary, but there the key for every column is the index number in the dataframe.

That idea makes me to write the below code.

```
df2 = df.to_dict()
values = ["s_101", "hyderabad", 10, 20, 16, 13, 15, 12, 12, 13, 25, 26, 25, 27, "good", "bad"] # This is the total row that we are going to add
i = 0
for x in df.columns:   # Here df.columns gives us the main dictionary key
    df2[x][101] = values[i]   # Here the 101 is our index number. It is also the key of the sub dictionary
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If all data in your Dataframe has the same dtype you might use a NumPy array. You can write rows directly into the predefined array and convert it to a dataframe at the end.
It seems to be even faster than converting a list of dicts.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_uppercase

startTime = time.perf_counter()
numcols, numrows = 5, 10000
npdf = np.ones((numrows, numcols))
for row in range(numrows):
    npdf[row, 0:] = np.random.randint(0, 100, (1, numcols))
df5 = pd.DataFrame(npdf, columns=list(ascii_uppercase[:numcols]))
print('Elapsed time: {:6.3f} seconds for {:d} rows'.format(time.perf_counter() - startTime, numOfRows))
print(df5.shape)
```

Comment: Re *"It seems to be even faster"*: Can you quantify that (by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64307807/edit))? What order are we talking about? 10% faster? 100% faster? 10 times faster? 1,000,000 times faster? At what scale (it could quadratic/exponential)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data frame `df` and want to add a **list** `new_list` as a new row to `df`, you can simply do:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = new_list
```

If you want to add a new **data frame** `new_df` under data frame `df`, then you can use:

```
df.append(new_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the 3 regularly mentioned options and their shortcomings for adding

- a **single row** (not multiple rows)
- optimized for **readability** (not for runtime performance, e.g. allow copy the DataFrame even though not preferred)
- columns can have different dtypes
- **keep the dtype** of all columns
- the index can have any form, e.g. 'holes' in an integer series
- keep the dtype of the `df.index`

The code setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'carId': [1, 4, 7], 'maxSpeed': [1.1, 4.4, 7.7]})
df = df.astype({
    'carId': np.uint16,
    'maxSpeed': np.float32,
})
df.set_index('carId', drop=False, inplace=True)
assert df.index.dtype == np.uint64

# the row to add
additional_row = [9, 9.9]
assert len(df.columns) == len(additional_row)
original_dtypes = df.dtypes
original_index_dtype = df.index.dtype
```

## 1) pd.concat()

```
df_new_row = pd.DataFrame([additional_row], columns=df.columns)
newDf = pd.concat([df, df_new_row])
assert df.dtypes.equals(newDf.dtypes)  # fails: carId is np.int64 and maxSpeed is np.float64
assert newDf.dtypes.equals(original_dtypes)  # fails: newDf.index.dype is np.float64
```

## 2) df.loc[]

```
df.loc[additional_row[0], :] = additional_row
assert df.index.dtype == original_index_dtype
assert df.dtypes.equals(original_dtypes)  # fails: carId and maxSpeed are np.float64
```

## 3) df.append()

depreciated since pandas 1.4.0

## solution

df.loc[] leaves the df.index intact, so I typically convert the types of the columns:

```
df.loc[additional_row[0], :] = additional_row
df = df.astype(original_dtypes)
assert df.index.dtype == original_index_dtype
assert df.dtypes.equals(original_dtypes)
```

Note that `df.astype()` creates a copy of the `df`. `df.astype(copy=False)` avoids this if you can accept the side effects of the copy parameter.

If you do not want to set the index explicitly, use e.g. `df.loc[df.index.max() + 1, :] = additional_row`. Note that `df.index.max()` fails if `df` is empty.

Unfortunately, [How to add an extra row to a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365513/how-to-add-an-extra-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe) has been marked as duplicate and points to this question. The title of this post "by appending one row at a time" implies that regularly adding multiple lines to a DataFrame is a good idea. I agree with many previous comments that there are probably not many uses cases for this. However, adding a single row to a DataFrame occurs more often, even though it's still an edge case.

Answer (score -1):

This code snippet uses a list of dictionaries to update the data frame. It adds on to [ShikharDua's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/create-a-pandas-dataframe-by-appending-one-row-at-a-time/17496530#17496530) and [Mikhail_Sam's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/create-a-pandas-dataframe-by-appending-one-row-at-a-time/47979665#47979665) answers.

```
import pandas as pd
colour = ["red", "big", "tasty"]
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
dict1={}
feat_list=[]
for x in colour:
    for y in fruits:
#         print(x, y)
        dict1 = dict([('x',x),('y',y)])
#         print(f'dict 1 {dict1}')
        feat_list.append(dict1)
#         print(f'feat_list {feat_list}')
feat_df=pd.DataFrame(feat_list)
feat_df.to_csv('feat1.csv')
```

Answer (score -3):

This will take care of adding an item to an empty DataFrame. The issue is that `df.index.max() == nan` for the first index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['timeMS', 'accelX', 'accelY', 'accelZ', 'gyroX', 'gyroY', 'gyroZ'])

df.loc[0 if math.isnan(df.index.max()) else df.index.max() + 1] = [x for x in range(7)]
```