# Creating an empty Pandas DataFrame, and then filling it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I'm starting from the pandas DataFrame documentation here: *[Introduction to data structures](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html)*

I'd like to iteratively fill the DataFrame with values in a time series kind of calculation. I'd like to initialize the DataFrame with columns A, B, and timestamp rows, all 0 or all NaN.

I'd then add initial values and go over this data calculating the new row from the row before, say `row[A][t] = row[A][t-1]+1` or so.

I'm currently using the code as below, but I feel it's kind of ugly and there must be a  way to do this with a DataFrame directly or just a better way in general.

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import scipy as s
base = dt.datetime.today().date()
dates = [ base - dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(9, -1, -1) ]

valdict = {}
symbols = ['A','B', 'C']
for symb in symbols:
    valdict[symb] = pd.Series( s.zeros(len(dates)), dates )

for thedate in dates:
    if thedate > dates[0]:
        for symb in valdict:
            valdict[symb][thedate] = 1 + valdict[symb][thedate - dt.timedelta(days=1)]
```

Comment: Never grow a DataFrame! It is always cheaper to append to a python list and then convert it to a DataFrame at the end, both in terms of memory and performance.

Comment: @cs95 What is functionally different between `.append` in pd and appending a list? I know `.append`in pandas copys the whole dataset to a new object ´, does pythons append work differently?

Comment: @Lamma please find details in my answer below. When appending to df, a new DataFrame is created each time in memory instead of using the existing one, which is quite frankly a waste.

Comment: append is now officially deprecated
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Answer (score 424, accepted):

Here's a couple of suggestions:

Use [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) for the index:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
index = pd.date_range(todays_date-datetime.timedelta(10), periods=10, freq='D')

columns = ['A','B', 'C']
```

*Note: we could create an empty DataFrame (with `NaN`s) simply by writing:*

```
df_ = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
df_ = df_.fillna(0) # With 0s rather than NaNs
```

To do these type of calculations for the data, use a [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) array:

```
data = np.array([np.arange(10)]*3).T
```

Hence we can create the DataFrame:

```
In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
            A  B  C
2012-11-29  0  0  0
2012-11-30  1  1  1
2012-12-01  2  2  2
2012-12-02  3  3  3
2012-12-03  4  4  4
2012-12-04  5  5  5
2012-12-05  6  6  6
2012-12-06  7  7  7
2012-12-07  8  8  8
2012-12-08  9  9  9
```

Comment: pd.date_range() does not work for me. I tried with DateRange (from eclipse's autocompletion), but that works with strings as date format, right?
The overall approach works though (I changed index to something else).

Comment: Is date_range a new feature that I may get by upgrading or is it in datatime (I changed to datetime, b/c I thought that's what you meant)

Comment: date_range is a factory function for creating datetime indexes and was [a new feature in 0.8.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.8.0/whatsnew.html?highlight=date_range), I would definitely recommend upgrading to the latest stable release (0.9.1) there are many bug fixes and new features. :)

Comment: In my experiences, creating a data frame of the necessary size filled with NaNs, and then filling up with values is much-much slower than creating a data frame with `index` x `0` dimensions (`columns = []`), and attaching one column in each turn of a loop. I mean `df[col_name] = pandas.Series([...])` in a loop iterating through column names. In the former case, not only the memory allocation takes time, but replacing NaNs with new values seems extremely slow.

Comment: @deeenes definitely. this answer should probably make that clearer - you very rarely (if ever) want to do create an empty Dataframe (of NaNs).

Comment: As per this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30267881/2302569
You need to assign the result of fillna, or pass param inplace=True

Answer (score 989):

## NEVER grow a DataFrame row-wise!

> TLDR; (just read the bold text)

Most answers here will tell you how to create an empty DataFrame and fill it out, but no one will tell you that it is a bad thing to do.

Here is my advice: **Accumulate data in a list, not a DataFrame.**

Use a list to collect your data, then initialise a DataFrame when you are ready. Either a *list-of-lists* or *list-of-dicts* format will work, [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) accepts both.

```
data = []
for row in some_function_that_yields_data():
    data.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`pd.DataFrame` converts the list of rows (where each row is a scalar value) into a DataFrame. If your function yields `DataFrame`s instead, call [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat).

Pros of this approach:

1. **It is always cheaper to append to a list and create a DataFrame in one go** than it is to create an empty DataFrame (or one of NaNs) and append to it over and over again.
2. **Lists also take up less memory and are a much lighter data structure to work with**, append, and remove (if needed).
3. **`dtypes` are automatically inferred** (rather than assigning `object` to all of them).
4. **A `RangeIndex` is automatically created for your data**, instead of you having to take care to assign the correct index to the row you are appending at each iteration.

If you aren't convinced yet, this is also mentioned in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

> Iteratively appending rows to a DataFrame can be more computationally
> intensive than a single concatenate. A better solution is to append
> those rows to a list and then concatenate the list with the original
> DataFrame all at once.

### pandas >= 2.0 Update: `append` has been removed!

`DataFrame.append` was deprecated in version 1.4 and removed from the pandas API entirely in version 2.0.

See the docs on [Deprecations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#deprecations) as well as [this github issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGIV6.png) that originally proposed its deprecation.

---

---

## These options are horrible

#### `append` or `concat` inside a loop

Here is the biggest mistake I've seen from beginners:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
for a, b, c in some_function_that_yields_data():
    df = df.append({'A': i, 'B': b, 'C': c}, ignore_index=True) # yuck
    # or similarly,
    # df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series({'A': i, 'B': b, 'C': c})], ignore_index=True)
```

Memory is re-allocated for every `append` or `concat` operation you have. Couple this with a loop and you have a **quadratic complexity operation**.

The other mistake associated with `df.append` is that users tend to forget **append is not an in-place function**, so the result must be assigned back. You also have to worry about the dtypes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df = df.append({'A': 1, 'B': 12.3, 'C': 'xyz'}, ignore_index=True)

df.dtypes
A     object   # yuck!
B    float64
C     object
dtype: object
```

Dealing with object columns is never a good thing, because pandas cannot vectorize operations on those columns. You will need to call the [`infer_objects()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html) method to fix it:

```
df.infer_objects().dtypes
A      int64
B    float64
C     object
dtype: object
```

#### `loc` inside a loop

I have also seen `loc` used to append to a DataFrame that was created empty:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
for a, b, c in some_function_that_yields_data():
    df.loc[len(df)] = [a, b, c]
```

As before, you have not pre-allocated the amount of memory you need each time, so **the memory is re-grown each time you create a new row**. It's just as bad as `append`, and even more ugly.

#### Empty DataFrame of NaNs

And then, there's creating a DataFrame of NaNs, and all the caveats associated therewith.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=range(5))
df
     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

It creates a DataFrame of `object` columns, like the others.

```
df.dtypes
A    object  # you DON'T want this
B    object
C    object
dtype: object
```

Appending still has all the issues as the methods above.

```
for i, (a, b, c) in enumerate(some_function_that_yields_data()):
    df.iloc[i] = [a, b, c]
```

---

---

## The Proof is in the Pudding

Timing these methods is the fastest way to see just how much they differ in terms of their memory and utility.

[image]

[Benchmarking code for reference.](https://gist.github.com/Coldsp33d/ea080f580ab3a3b75c2f40c201d50164)

Comment: This is literally in the documentation. "Iteratively appending rows to a DataFrame can be more computationally intensive than a single concatenate. A better solution is to append those rows to a list and then concatenate the list with the original DataFrame all at once." https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Comment: Also "Note It is worth noting that concat() (and therefore append()) makes a full copy of the data, and that constantly reusing this function can create a significant performance hit. If you need to use the operation over several datasets, use a list comprehension." https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#concatenating-objects

Comment: So, what do I do when my data "comes in" as 1d lists one at a time with each one representing a column in a data frame? How do I append them together before converting into a dataframe? It seems that `list1.apped(list2)` insets a list within another list rather than adding a column. Thanks

Comment: @Confounded That's a different problem than the one asked here, but it should be ok to assign one column at a time to an empty Dataframe. The issue arises with successive appending of rows.

Comment: You're not wrong, but if I am mapping from one DF to another, I can only take advantage of vectorized columns if I have initialized the new DF with the correct number of rows (that matches the other)

Comment: @Alex you can just assign one column at a time, but it depends on your use case and "mapping from one DF to another" sounds a bit ambiguous

Comment: @cs95 in my case I have a requirement of mapping into a new dataframe from two others, but the rows are of varying size. I needed to initialize the full row count in the new, to 'fill' it using a specialised function to achieve it. I did not use append however.

Comment: @Alex it seems like you can reindex the smaller dataframe with the larger dataframe's index -- but again your comment is still a bit ambiguous. Consider opening a new question if you would like some suggestions on how to improve your existing code (if possible) cheers!

Comment: @cs95 appreciate the offer - I think my code is fine, its working well, and fast over large data sets. I’m not doing anything outside of your suggestions… I’m not growing a data set as I’m initlaizing it with the right number of rows. I’m then using .loc in chunks to fill the column. It actually works really nicely.

Comment: The problem with re-indexing is that backfill or pad etc - none of the options matched my use case, so I wrote a simple chunking fill function.

Comment: Sorry @cs95 I am trying to understand this line `a, b, c in some_function_that_yields_data()` does the yield data function have to return these lists a, b, c?  Or are a, b, c in the global environment? How do you preserve type? I am needing to transpose, and then getting a pd of objects so I am not doing it right.  Please can you explain `for a, b, c in some_function_that_yields_data()` line more.

Comment: @micstr a, b and c are individual, atomic scalar values rather than lists. If you already have the lists of data available, just call `pd.DataFrame([a_list, b_list, c_list])`

Comment: what if you are using pandas inexpensively (i.e., datasets are small ~10 or less) and new items are appended/removed based on time order in hours/days rather than seconds and performance isn't important. Panda dataframes offer some really unique features for filtering and print nice tables for CLI tools that I can't really ignore and if I want to use it to manage objects, I think this is a use case that is ignored for dataframes unless there are better data structures out there (outside of reimplementing your own using lists and dicts).

Comment: I've responded to this question ad nauseam "what if the data is small" ... but what if it's not, and you don't know how to process it because you've only been working with small datasets until now that you could get by with suboptimal solutions?

Comment: One problem I see with this answer is that if the OP is dealing with time-series data meaning a use case is to append data that comes available real-time then appending to the list and then creating a dataframe is also computationally expensive. Whether if its done this way or growing a dataframe iteratively, you deal with the same space complexity problem.

Comment: @LeanMan space complexity of list append is `O(n)` amortized, for dataframes it is `O(n ** 2)` so it is not the same.

Comment: Interesting, where can I find a resource that goes over complexities for dataframes? I have been looking for one myself.

Comment: @LeanMan the most notable mention I am aware of is the Notes section of the [append docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas-dataframe-append)

Comment: So, if appending row-wise is bad but appending column-wise (e.g. `df['new column'] = column`) is okay, why isn't it be best practice to append new rows as columns and then to transpose the df in the end (i.e. before printing/saving)?

Comment: Great answer! For me `df = pd.concat(data)` worked instead of `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

Comment: So then you have to check to see if a data variable that might contain the panda dataframes is an empty list or an empty panda dataframe, and they have different ways to do that.

Comment: "this github issue" is a bad link. It links to an image.

Comment: This is really the key takeaway here, and should stand out as the most important part of this answer I think: _"Here is my advice: Accumulate data in a list, not a DataFrame. Use a list to collect your data, then initialise a DataFrame when you are ready. Either a list-of-lists or list-of-dicts format will work, `pd.DataFrame` accepts both."_

Answer (score 227):

If you simply want to create an empty data frame and fill it with some incoming data frames later, try this:

```
newDF = pd.DataFrame() #creates a new dataframe that's empty
newDF = newDF.append(oldDF, ignore_index = True) # ignoring index is optional
# try printing some data from newDF
print newDF.head() #again optional
```

In this example I am using [this pandas doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) to create a new data frame and then using [append](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to write to the newDF with data from oldDF.

If I have to keep appending new data into this newDF from more than
one oldDFs, I just use a for loop to iterate over
[pandas.DataFrame.append()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

Note: `append()` is deprecated since version 1.4.0. Use `concat()`.

Comment: Please note that `append` (and similarly `concat`) copies the full dataset to a new object every time, hence, iterating and appending can and will cause a major performance hit. for more info refer to: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: @MoustafaAAtta What are the alternatives to append iteratively data to the dataframe ?

Comment: @MoustafaAAtta Is Fred answer in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe better on this point of view ?

Comment: @MoustafaAAtta you can perhaps append just rows to a dataframe, it will still create a new object but for smaller datasets, might be useful. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#appending-rows-to-a-dataframe

Comment: Note that append method is officially deprecated check the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Answer (score 169):

**Initialize empty frame with column names**

```
import pandas as pd

col_names =  ['A', 'B', 'C']
my_df  = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)
my_df
```

**Add a new record to a frame**

```
my_df.loc[len(my_df)] = [2, 4, 5]
```

You also might want to pass a dictionary:

```
my_dic = {'A':2, 'B':4, 'C':5}
my_df.loc[len(my_df)] = my_dic
```

**Append another frame to your existing frame**

```
col_names =  ['A', 'B', 'C']
my_df2  = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)
my_df = my_df.append(my_df2)
```

---

**Performance considerations**

If you are adding rows inside a loop consider performance issues. For around the first 1000 records "my_df.loc" performance is better, but it gradually becomes slower by increasing the number of records in the loop.

If you plan to do thins inside a big loop (say 10M‌ records or so), you are better off using a mixture of these two;
fill a dataframe with iloc until the size gets around 1000, then append it to the original dataframe, and empty the temp dataframe.
This would boost your performance by around 10 times.

Comment: `my_df = my_df.append(my_df2)` does not work for me unless I specify `ignore_index=True`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([rows,columns])
```

Then fill it.

Comment: And for the equivalent NaN-initalized array, use [the device driver I wrote](https://github.com/njwhite/devnan/blob/c472a244b0d8a60daca35ddd2a65b14f0f2d0451/test_driver.py#L21-L22)!

Answer (score 1):

Assume a dataframe with 19 rows

```
index=range(0,19)
index

columns=['A']
test = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
```

Keeping Column A as a constant

```
test['A']=10
```

Keeping column b as a variable given by a loop

```
for x in range(0,19):
    test.loc[[x], 'b'] = pd.Series([x], index = [x])
```

You can replace the first x in `pd.Series([x], index = [x])` with any value

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to make a dynamic dataframe from several lists with a loop

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
y = [22,12,34,22,65,24,12,11]
z = ['as','ss','wa', 'ss','er','fd','ga','mf']
names = ['Bob', 'Liz', 'chop']
```

a loop

```
def dataF(x,y,z,names):
    res = []

    for t in zip(x,y,z):
        res.append(t)

    return pd.DataFrame(res,columns=names)
```

Result

```
dataF(x,y,z,names)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pandas dataframes can be thought of as a dictionary of pandas columns (pandas Series). Just like a dictionary where adding a new key-value pair is inexpensive, adding a new column/columns is very efficient (and dataframes are *meant* to be grown horizontally like that).

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = range(0, 2000_000, 2)   # add one column
df[['B', 'C']] = ['a', 'b']       # add multiple columns
```

---

On the other hand, just like updating every value of a dictionary requires looping over the entire dictionary, enlarging a dataframe vertically by adding new rows is very inefficient. It's especially inefficient if new rows are added one-by-one in a loop (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76132725/19123103) for a benchmark comparing the possible options).

If new row values depend on previous row values as in the OP, then depending on the number of columns, it might be better to loop over a pre-initialized dataframe of zeros or grow a Python dictionary in a loop and construct a dataframe after (if there are more than 500 columns, it's probably better to loop over the dataframe). But it's never optimal to mix the two, in other words, growing a dictionary of pandas Series will be extremely slow.<sup>1</sup>

```py
dates = pd.date_range(end=pd.Timestamp('now'), periods=10000, freq='D').date
symbols = [f"col{i}" for i in range(10)]

# initialize a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=dates, columns=symbols)
# update it in a loop
for i, thedate in enumerate(df.index):
    if thedate > df.index[0]:
        df.loc[thedate] = df.loc[df.index[i-1]] + 1


# build a nested dictionary
data = {}
for i, thedate in enumerate(dates):
    for symb in symbols:
        if thedate > dates[0]:
            data[symb][thedate] = 1 + data[symb][dates[i-1]]
        else:
            data[symb] = {thedate: 0}
# construct a dataframe after
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

<sup>1: That said, for this specific example, `cumsum()` or even `range()` would seemingly work without even looping over the rows. This part of the answer is more about cases where looping is unavoidable, such as financial data manipulation etc.</sup>