# df.fillna(0) command won't replace NaN values with 0

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, nan

I'm trying to replace the NaN values generated in the code below to 0. I don't understand what the below won't work. It still keeps the NaN values.

```
df_pubs=pd.read_sql("select Conference, Year, count(*) as totalPubs from publications where year>=1991 group by conference, year", db)

df_pubs['Conference'] = df_pubs['Conference'].str.encode('utf-8')

df_pubs = df_pubs.pivot(index='Conference', columns='Year', values='totalPubs')
df_pubs.fillna(0)

print df_pubs
```

`print df produces` this:

```
Year                                                                                       1991  \
Conference                                                                                        
                                                                                            223   
10th Anniversary Colloquium of UNU/IIST                                                     NaN   
15. WLP                                                                                     NaN   
1999 ACM SIGMOD Workshop on Research Issues in Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery          NaN   
25 Years CSP                                                                                NaN
```

Comment: You need `df_pubs = df_pubs.fillna(0)`. `fillna` doesn't modify the original DataFrame.

Comment: Most pandas operations return a copy by default, some have param `inplace=True`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `fillna`:

```
df_pubs = df_pubs.fillna(0)
```

or pass param `inplace=True`:

```
df_pubs.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna)

You could modify your code to this:

```
df_pubs = df_pubs.pivot(index='Conference', columns='Year', values='totalPubs').fillna(0)
```

which would work but it's debatable whether the `fillna` is readable here.

Comment: I tried to save the df as an sql table using: `df_pubs.to_sql('conferences_pubs', db, flavor='sqlite', if_exists='replace', index=True)` when `index=False`, it works but I need the Conference Name (ie the index) to be added as a column, so when I put index=True it gives me an error: `ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str)`. It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings. Any ideas why it does that?

Comment: don't know but it sounds like the encoding of your db is not set up to accept utf-8, can you change this? I don't know much about this topic to be honest so if you're still stuck I'd post a new question