# How do I append one pandas DataFrame to another?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with appending of dataframe.
I try to execute this code

```
df_all = pd.read_csv('data.csv', error_bad_lines=False, chunksize=1000000)
urls = pd.read_excel('url_june.xlsx')
substr = urls.url.values.tolist()
df_res = pd.DataFrame()
for df in df_all:
    for i in substr:
        res = df[df['url'].str.contains(i)]
        df_res.append(res)
```

And when I try to save `df_res` I get empty dataframe.
`df_all` looks like

```
ID,"url","used_at","active_seconds"
b20f9412f914ad83b6611d69dbe3b2b4,"mobiguru.ru/phones/apple/comp/32gb/apple_iphone_5s.html",2015-10-01 00:00:25,1
b20f9412f914ad83b6611d69dbe3b2b4,"mobiguru.ru/phones/apple/comp/32gb/apple_iphone_5s.html",2015-10-01 00:00:31,30
f85ce4b2f8787d48edc8612b2ccaca83,"4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=634566&view=getnewpost",2015-10-01 00:01:49,2
d3b0ef7d85dbb4dbb75e8a5950bad225,"shop.mts.ru/smartfony/mts/smartfon-smart-sprint-4g-sim-lock-white.html?utm_source=admitad&utm_medium=cpa&utm_content=300&utm_campaign=gde_cpa&uid=3",2015-10-01 00:03:19,34
078d388438ebf1d4142808f58fb66c87,"market.yandex.ru/product/12675734/spec?hid=91491&track=char",2015-10-01 00:03:48,2
d3b0ef7d85dbb4dbb75e8a5950bad225,"avito.ru/yoshkar-ola/telefony/mts",2015-10-01 00:04:21,4
d3b0ef7d85dbb4dbb75e8a5950bad225,"shoppingcart.aliexpress.com/order/confirm_order",2015-10-01 00:04:25,1
d3b0ef7d85dbb4dbb75e8a5950bad225,"shoppingcart.aliexpress.com/order/confirm_order",2015-10-01 00:04:26,9
```

and `urls` looks like

```
url
shoppingcart.aliexpress.com/order/confirm_order
ozon.ru/?context=order_done&number=
lk.wildberries.ru/basket/orderconfirmed
lamoda.ru/checkout/onepage/success/quick
mvideo.ru/confirmation?_requestid=
eldorado.ru/personal/order.php?step=confirm
```

When I print `res` in a loop it doesn't empty. But when I try print in a loop `df_res` after append, it return empty dataframe.
I can't find my error. How can I fix it?

Comment: To new users coming to this post after getting a "Why am I getting "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'?": `append` has been removed from the API from pandas >= 2.0 in order to discourage iteratively appending DataFrames inside a loop. The idiomatic way in 2023 to append dataframes is to first collate your data into a python list and then call pd.concat. [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76020741/4909087)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation for `pd.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

> Append rows of other to the end of this frame, **returning a new object**. Columns not in this frame are added as new columns.

(emphasis mine).

Try

```
df_res = df_res.append(res)
```

---

Incidentally, note that pandas isn't that efficient for creating a DataFrame by successive concatenations. You might try this, instead:

```
all_res = []
for df in df_all:
    for i in substr:
        res = df[df['url'].str.contains(i)]
        all_res.append(res)

df_res = pd.concat(all_res)
```

This first creates a list of all the parts, then creates a DataFrame from all of them once at the end.

Comment: thank you for explanation. Sometimes `df_res.append(res)` works, but sometimes only `df_res = df_res.append(res)` works. But I don't know why does it happen

Comment: @PetrPetrov Are you working in an interactive environment?

Comment: +1 for pointing out the inefficiency of using this to concatenate several dataframes in a loop. I keep finding that in code and it drives me crazy.

Comment: append has been deprecated since version 1.5  

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Answer (score 23):

> ### Why am I getting "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'?

### pandas >= 2.0 `append` has been removed, use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) instead<sup>1</sup>

Starting from pandas 2.0, `append` has been removed from the API. It was previously deprecated in version 1.4. See the docs on [Deprecations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#deprecations) as well as [this github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35407) that originally proposed its deprecation.

The rationale for its removal was to discourage iteratively growing DataFrames in a loop (which is what people typically use append for). This is because append makes a new copy at each stage, resulting in quadratic complexity in memory.

<sub>1. This assume you're appending one DataFrame to another. If you're appending a row to a DataFrame, the solution is slightly different - see below.</sub>

---

The idiomatic way to append DataFrames is to collect all your smaller DataFrames into a list, and then make one single call to [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). Here's a(n oversimplified) example

```
df_list = []
for df in some_function_that_yields_dfs():
    df_list.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Note that if you are trying to append one row at a time rather than one DataFrame at a time, the solution is even simpler.

```
data = []
for a, b, c from some_function_that_yields_data():
    data.append([a, b, c])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

More information in [Creating an empty Pandas DataFrame, and then filling it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56746204/4909087)

Answer (score 5):

### If we want append based on index:

```
df_res = pd.DataFrame(data = None, columns= df.columns)

all_res = []

d1 = df.ix[index-10:index-1,]     #it will take 10 rows before i-th index

all_res.append(d1)

df_res = pd.concat(all_res)
```