# Append a dataframe at the end of another dataframe via Pytjon

Tags: python, dataframe, append

I need to append a dataframe to another dataframe, the columns of tha dataframes have no names.
This is my code:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(fileName_1, header=0, index= False)
df2 = pd.read_excel(fileName_2, header=0, index= False)
df2 = df2.append(df1, ignore_index = True)
```

**this is the output of this code**

```
  nbr de Kilomètres parcourus    2        Nombre de reboot    0
0                         NaN  NaN   Passage en mode privé  1.0
1                         NaN  NaN  Passage en mode public  0.0
```

**but I need it to be as follows:**

```
nbr de Kilomètres parcourus    2        
Nombre de reboot    0
Passage en mode privé  1.0
Passage en mode public  0.0
```

But it seems like python consider the dataframe with only one row as empty and I don't know why

```
df2: Empty DataFrame Columns: [nbr de Kilomètres parcourus, 3] Index: []
```

how can I append it in rows not in columns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: append dataframe to another df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815646/pandas-append-dataframe-to-another-df)

Comment: please copy and paste df1 and df2 here

Comment: df1:         `Nombre de reboot  0`
`0   Passage en mode privé  1`
`1  Passage en mode public  3`
df2: 
`Empty DataFrame`
`Columns: [nbr de Kilomètres parcourus, 3]`
`Index: []`

Comment: @AmitKumar sorry but I couldn't understand the code that you referred to or how is it related to my code

Comment: @AmitKumar I tried to run the code that u meantioned Iand I got an error: res = df[df['url'].str.contains(i)]

TypeError: string indices must be integers