# How to preallocate memory for a large pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need to create a large dataframe to save my data. It has 30001 columns, 1000 rows. For the data type, 30000 columns are int64, and the last columns is a hash values.

So I first create an empty dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columnNames, data=np.empty(shape=(1000, 30001)))
```

And then I create a Series based on dataframe's columns:

```
record = pd.Series(index=df.columns)
```

Then in a loop I'll populate the record and assign them to dataframe:

```
loop:
    record[0:30000] = values   #fill record with values
    record['hash']= hash_value
    df.loc[index] = record     <==== this is slow
    index += 1
```

When I debug on my code, I found the above step which assign record to a row is horribly slow.

My guess is that if I could create a dataframe with exact the size preallocated, then assigning the record to each row will be much faster.

So can I create the dataframe with full size preallocated?

(note: my original dataframe does not have the 'hash' column, it runs without any performance issue. Recently I found I need this additional hash column, which is a string value. And this performance issue occurred right after this new column added)

Comment: What method are you hoping to use to fill the dataframe? You could create a dataframe with the same column titles, and numpy arrays of 'None' (with dtype specified). I don't really know why you'd want to do this, unless you are doing something 'un pandas esque' later on when populating that frame.

Comment: I did try create dataframe with column tiltles and 'None' numpy array. It worked fine before. But when I changed my dataframe to add a new column which is used to store 32 bytes string, then filling this dataframe become horribly slow. My guess is that each time a new record is added it needs to expand memory for the string field.

Comment: Adding 'cells' to a dataframe is a slow process. This is due to all the internal checking that pandas does when an assignment is made. The best way to alleviate this is to add series / lists / arrays of data to the dataframe at once, as the checking can be made against the 'collection' object and not a single instance of type. Is it possible for you to create the DataFrame and assign arrays instead of specific values?

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I did as workaround. I create a list, and later add this list as the additional column to the df.

Comment: you shouldn't fill your dataframe row by row, see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784192/creating-an-empty-pandas-dataframe-and-then-filling-it