# TypeError when initializing data frame with Int64 data type

Tags: python, pandas, int64

I'm trying to initialize a data frame with `Int64` data type but keep getting a `TypeError`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3], columns=['a','b'], dtype='Int64')

TypeError: values must be a 1D list-like
```

What can I do?

Comment: It seems like a bug in pandas. Maybe construct with floats and then cast to Int64? `df = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3], columns=['a','b']).astype('Int64') `

Comment: Thanks @ayhan, that works, although `df['a'] = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2],data={'a':[1,3]})` seems to revert `a` to `float64` again. But I guess I can use the same trick on the new data frame

Comment: Why are you initializing an empty DataFrame? I'm a little worried that you're going down the route of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56746204/4909087).

Comment: I agree with @cs95, some more context/clarification would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[pd.Series()]*3,index=[1,2,3], columns=['a','b'], dtype='Int64')
```