# How to create a empty dataframe and appened it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new in python and pandas. I have to read few csv files which have same columns and created a resultant dataFrame(which have all the rows from every csv files).
I tried it but when i print dataframe, it's print
Empty DataFrame

Columns: []
Index: []

code is:

```
def readCSV(dir):
list = getFilesInDir(dir) #  my function which returns list of files.
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame()    
for name in list:
    df = pandas.read_csv(name)
    dataframe.append(df)

print(dataframe)
```

Comment: This is literally https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784192/creating-an-empty-pandas-dataframe-then-filling-it, please don't fill an empty DataFrame, it is a bad practice in pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataFrame.append` **is not** `list.append`. You need to assign the result back.

```
dataframe = dataframe.append(df)
```

However, appending within a loop is not advised as it needlessly copies data. You should append to a list and concatenate once in the end. We can turn the loop into a list comprehension within `concat`.

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(name) for name in list])
```