# How to store data in dataframe with for loop request. Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to store as data frame with for loop request.

```
import time
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
from newspaper import Article

countries = df["Country"].unique().tolist()
print(countries) 

#Output:
-----------
['Malaysia', 'ireland', 'CZ', 'India', 'USA']
```

Now like if want to get google news data and store all data by country in a Dataframe.

```
list_country = []
df = pd.DataFrame([])
for country in tqdm(countries1): 
    googlenews = GoogleNews(start=Start_date,end=End_date)
    googlenews.set_lang('en')
    googlenews.set_encode('utf-8')
    googlenews.get_news(country)
    googlenews.total_count()
    result=googlenews.result()
    data=pd.DataFrame(result)
    df = df.append(data)
    df['Country'] = country
    list_country.append(country)

df.head()
```

Expected output like:

[image]

But in result only store last country's result.

Comment: Have you tried to remove `tqdm` and iterate over `countries` list directly, just to check?

Comment: please avoid using loops and appending to dataframe. It is not advised. See this link. I also recommend that we don't suggest solutions that have for loop with a df.append() at the [end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784192/creating-an-empty-pandas-dataframe-then-filling-it/56746204#56746204) as suggested by @cs95.

Comment: Instead create a dictionary with country as key and all the values as column:value. Then create a dataframe. It will create the dataframe for you.

Comment: @JoeFerndz Yes, did the same and getting the expected result. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before append data frame add current country in it,
Create country column and add current country name for that search result.

```
import datetime
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
from newspaper import Article
import pandas as pd

Start_date = str((datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=30)).strftime ('%d/%m/%Y'))
End_date = str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime ('%d/%m/%Y'))

list_country = []
df = pd.DataFrame([])
for country in tqdm(countries): 
    googlenews = GoogleNews(start=Start_date,end=End_date)
    googlenews.set_lang('en')
    googlenews.set_encode('utf-8')
    googlenews.get_news(country)
    googlenews.total_count()
    result=googlenews.result()
    data=pd.DataFrame(result)
    data["Country"] = country
    df = df.append(data)

#Check result     
df.shape
df[90:100]
```

Answer (score 0):

it didn't store only the last country data; it's simply change all the strings in the country column to the last country. you can use `iloc` in the dataframe to limits this effect

```
import datetime
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
from newspaper import Article
import pandas as pd

countries = ['Malaysia', 'ireland', 'CZ', 'India', 'USA']

End_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()

delta = datetime.timedelta(days = 0)
Start_date = datetime.datetime.now().date() - delta

googlenews = GoogleNews(lang='en',
                        start=Start_date,
                        end=End_date,
                        encode = 'utf-8')

all_df = pd.DataFrame([])
for country in tqdm(countries): 
    googlenews.get_news(country)
    googlenews.total_count()
    print(googlenews.total_count())
    result=googlenews.result()
    data=pd.DataFrame(result)
    if all_df.empty:
        all_df = all_df.append(data)
        all_df['Country'] = country
    else:
        current_size = len(all_df)
        all_df = all_df.append(data)
        all_df.iloc[current_size:,8:] = country
    googlenews.clear()
```