# pandas: how write data to csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas

As a fresher I don't know how to write a csv file help to store a data in csv file.
I wanted file header should be like this and below the header, data should be aliened. thanks in advance
(0,0,"Product_Url")
(0,1,"Product_Manufacturer")
(0,2,"Product_Model")
(0,3,"Product_color")
(0,4,"Product_memory")
(0,5,"Product_Price")
(0,6,"Currency")
(0,7,"VAT")
(0,8,"Shipping Cost")
(0,9,"Country")
(0,10,"Date")

```
import xlwt
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import time
from datetime import date

class expert:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url='https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/Vendita_Smartphone_W8D.aspx'
        self.country='IT'
        self.currency='euro'
        self.VAT='Included'
    def experts(self):
        try:
            driver=webdriver.Chrome()            
            driver.get(self.url)
            today = date.today()
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.maximize_window()
            x=1           
            while True:             
                containers = []
                flag = False
                containers =driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class="col-xs-12 skywalker_riga skywalker_riga_articolo"]')                 
                for container in containers:                      
                    try:
                        url = container.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="skywalker_riga_nome"]')
                        urls = url.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
                        if urls != "":
                            print(urls)
                            flag = True
                    except:
                        pass
                    try:
                        title = container.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="skywalker_riga_nome"] h3').text
                        if title != "":
                            print(title)
                            flag = True
                    except:
                        pass
                    try:
                        price = container.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="skywalker_riga_prezzo"]').text
                        if price  != "":
                            print(price)
                            flag = True
                    except:
                        pass
                print("flag value is:" +str(flag))   
                if flag==False:
                    break
                try:
                    x+=1
                    time.sleep(5)
                    driver.get(self.url+"?pagina="+str(x))                    
                    print("next page") 
                except:
                    break
        except:
            pass
expertit=expert()
expertit.experts()
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas [dataframe to CSV](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) can do this easily,

**Step1:** [Start with an empty dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784192/creating-an-empty-pandas-dataframe-then-filling-it) and fill it while you loop

```py
pypd_df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Product_Url","Product_Manufacturer","Product_Model","Product_color","Product_memory","Product_Price","Currency","VAT","Shipping Cost","Country","Date"])
```

**Step2:** [Add rows to existing dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/create-a-pandas-dataframe-by-appending-one-row-at-a-time) or [consider this while you deal with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62734983/16406491) dataframes in python.

```py
pypd_df1.loc[len(pypd_df1)] = [Product_Url_var_name, Product_Manufacturer_var_name, ...]
```

You may find [Python's writelines](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_writelines.asp) method interesting sometimes.