# Python parsing unstructured data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file that contains following data in it. I am trying to parse the data.

```
08/23/21 04:00:05 AM


/* ----------------- data1----------------- */ 

make: honda   model: civic
year: 2019
trim: "lx"
owner: phillip

/* ----------------- data2----------------- */ 

make: toyota  model: highlander
year: 2021
trim: "Platinum"
```

**I want to see the data like this:**

```
Make, Model, Year, trim, Owner
Honda, civic, 2019, lx, phillip
toyota, highlander, 2021, platinum, Rex
```

**here is my code:**
I was tryin to create dictionary and then load to panda dataframe. I think i am not on right direction.

```
def fix_line(record):
    #split every field and value into a seperate line
    results = []
    mini_collection = []
    if not record.startswith("/*"):
        #for data in record.rstrip('\n').strip().split('   '):
        for data in record.rstrip('\n').split('   '):
            if ':' not in data:
                mini_collection.append(data)
            else:
                results.append(data)
    return results
                    
def create_dictionary(data):   
    record = {}                
    for line in fix_line(data):
        line = line.strip()
        name, value = line.split(':', 1)
        record[name.strip()] = value.strip()
    return record
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this format? Is this a standard output from some other program or system? Can we make guarantees about the dataset like that data always starts on line 4, and every block has values for all keys? Or do we have to interpret everything on the fly?

Comment: @HenryEcker yes, it is a file from another system. Yes, every data starts from line 4. Some blocks may have more keys and values, and some may have less keys and value.

Answer (score 2):

Heres one way:

```
import re
import yaml #python -m pip install pyyaml
import pandas as pd 

s = """08/23/21 04:00:05 AM


/* ----------------- data1----------------- */ 

make: honda
model: civic
year: 2019
trim: lx
owner: phillip

/* ----------------- data2----------------- */ 

make: toyota
model: highlander
year: 2021
trim: Platinum
owner: Rex
"""

lines = re.split("/*\s*/", s)
records = [yaml.load(line) for line in lines if "make:" in line]
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

output:

```
     make       model  year      trim    owner
0   honda       civic  2019        lx  phillip
1  toyota  highlander  2021  Platinum      Rex
```

Comment: how do I apply re.split if I have data like this?
/* ----------------- data1----------------- */ 

make: honda   model: civic
year: 2019
trim: lx
owner: phillip

/* ----------------- data2----------------- */ 

make: toyota   model: highlander
year: 2021
trim: Platinum
owner: Rex

Comment: @annon01 - I have made some changes to the input file, trim has value with double quote and owner does not exist data2. what changes I should do in your code?

Comment: you will have to write a custom cleaning function if your data is dirty - there is no easy solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Try using `re.finditer` with the following `pattern` to create `dictionary` based on finding. Then append to a dataframe.

```
import re

pattern = """
    (?P<make>(?<=(make:\ ))\w+) #use lookbehind regex to get make
    (\s + model: \ )            #Skip to model
    (?P<model>\w+)              #Get Model
    (\s year: \ )               #Skip to year
    (?P<year>\d+)               #Get year
    (\s + trim: \ ")            #Skip to trim
    (?P<trim>\w+)               #Get trim
    ("\s)                       #Skip to owner
    (?P<owner>.*)               #Get owner
"""

df = pd.DataFrame([item.groupdict() for item in re.finditer(pattern, data, re.VERBOSE)])
df["owner"] = df["owner"].str.replace("owner: ", "")
df
Out[563]: 
     make       model  year      trim    owner
0   honda       civic  2019        lx  phillip
1  toyota  highlander  2021  Platinum
```

Comment: Not the DV, but [never grow a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56746204/15497888). `DataFrame.append` in a loop has quadratic time complexity. It would be better to add all of those dictionaries to a list then build the DataFrame at the end. `df = pd.DataFrame([item.groupdict() for item in re.finditer(pattern, data, re.VERBOSE)])`

Comment: @HenryEcker good idea. i learn something new today. Thanks for feedback!

Comment: @RaymondToh - I have modified my input file data little bit, like trim has value with double quote and owner does not exist data2 and make and model are on one line. how do I write the pattern for this?

Comment: @st_bones are you able to provide me a sample? Also, do use `list comprehension` method provided by Henry and mark a tick to the solution.

Comment: @RaymondToh  sample data is in the original request description, I have modified the sample data in the description box. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @st_bones ur data2 output should not have rex anymore?

Comment: @st_bones this is the best results I can get using `regex`. Because `data1` and `data2` do not have the same pattern. so the `str.replace` is needed. If this work for you, do upvote and approve the solution :)