# Pandas, drop row if column contains partial string not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV that I'm cleaning up with the help of Python/Pandas however there is some duplicates that I want to clean up where everthing i have tried fails to drop the row,

So Target Colum is "Title", i want to remove entire row if string inside column contains the partial string 'NQR',
I've tried:

```
df[~df['Title'].isin(['NQR', na=False])]

df[~df.Title.str.contains("NQR", na=False)]

discard = ["NQR"]

df[~df.Title.str.contains('|'.join(discard), na=False)]
```

none of these work, entire script runs with no errors and rows containing these are still there!

Comment: Are you assigning the result back to `df`? These things all return a new df, they don't modify in place.

Comment: [why-arent-pandas-operations-in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69969482/why-arent-pandas-operations-in-place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use the [str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) built-in `case` parameter if you don't want to preform a case sensitive search.

```
df = df[~df['Title'].str.contains('NQR', na=False, case=False)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: This one worked an absolute treat - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use either (for lowercase):

```py
df = df[~df['Title'].str.lower().str.contains('nqr')]
```

or (for uppercase)

```py
df = df[~df['Title'].str.upper().str.contains('NQR')]
```

Filter explanation :

- first part of filter converts in lower or uppercase
- second part checks for string