# Appending floats to empty pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, recursion, append, typeerror

I am trying to build a recursive function that will take data from a specific dataframe, do a little math with it, and append that result to a new dataframe. My current code looks as follows

```
div1, div2, div3 = [pd.DataFrame(index = range(1), columns = ['g']) for i in range(3)]

# THIS IS NOT WORKING FOR SOME REASON
def stats(div, obp):
    loop = 1
    while loop <= 3:
        games = obp['g'].sum() / 2
        div = div.append(games)
        loop += 1
    if loop == 2:
        stats(div2, dii_obp, dii_hr)
    elif loop == 3:
        stats(div3, diii_obp, diii_hr)
    else:
        print('Invalid')
        
stats(div1, di_obp)
```

I get an error that reads:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

div1, and di_obp are dataframes and ['g'] is a column in the di_obp dataframe.

I have tried making the variable games into an empty list, and a series and got different errors. I am not sure what I should try next. Any help is much appreciated!!

here is the head of the di_obp dataframe, the dii_obp and the diii_obp dataframes are the same but with different values.

```
print(di_obp.head())
      rank  team     g      ab      h     bb   hbp    sf    sh   
608  213.0  None  56.0  1947.0  526.0  182.0  55.0  19.0  22.0 
609  214.0  None  36.0  1099.0  287.0  124.0  25.0  11.0  24.0  
610  215.0  None  35.0  1099.0  247.0  159.0  51.0  11.0  24.0 
611  216.0  None  36.0  1258.0  317.0  157.0  30.0  11.0   7.0 
612  217.0  None  38.0  1136.0  281.0  138.0  41.0  14.0  10.0
```

CURRENT PROBLEM:

```
div1, div2, div3 = [pd.DataFrame(index= range(1), columns = ['g']) for i in range(3)]

def stats(div, obp):
    loop = 1
    while loop <= 3:
        while loop <= 3:
            games = obp['g'].sum() / 2
            div[0] = div[0].append({'g': games}, ignore_index=True)
            loop += 1
        if loop == 2:
            stats([div2], dii_obp)
        elif loop == 3:
            stats([div3], diii_obp)
        else:
            print('Done')

stats([div1], di_obp)
```

this does not return an error, but my dataframes are still empty

Comment: Your example is almost perfectly self-contained, which is great, but can you provide an example of `di_obp`?

Comment: yes sure thing, just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending to a dataframe is [generally not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56746204). Instead, you should accumulate your data in lists and then create dataframes from those lists:

```
div1, div2, div3 = [[] for _ in range(3)]

def stats(div, obp):
    loop = 1
    while loop <= 3:
        while loop <= 3:
            games = obp['g'].sum() / 2
            div.append(games)
            loop += 1
        if loop == 2:
            stats(div2, dii_obp)
        elif loop == 3:
            stats(div3, diii_obp)
        else:
            print('Done')

stats(div1, di_obp)

div1_df, div2_df, div2_df = [pd.DataFrame({'g': div}) for div in [div1, div2, div3]]
```

Comment: When I change the div1, div2, and div3 variables from dataframes to lists, and run the code you suggested, I get a new error:

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Why change them to lists? Keep all your dataframes just like they were. The point of this solution is only for when you use the dataframes in functions - you can't pass by reference in Python, so this is a workaround.

Comment: well I tried it because when I do it with a dataframe I get:

Comment: TypeError: Can only append a dict if ignore_index=True

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry, that's my fault. You're supposed to call `append` with `ignore_index=True`. Check the answer now.

Comment: and when I make it true, the dataframe is still totally empty

Comment: Will you please add the code you're working with to the question? I think if I can see it I can help you better ;)

Comment: Yeah I am sorry haha I am just excited to have some help, I appriciate it

Comment: No problem! It's fun :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241843/discussion-between-jensen-ray-and-richardec).