# How to transpose data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

I am working on a data frame which initially looks like :

```
         Date            Unnamed: 0  ...               Co             Ca
0           0                   NaN  ...              NaN            NaN
1  2022-01-21               Blablab  ...  33333333.333333  555555.555555
2  2022-01-21  BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBl  ...  44444444.444444  666666.666666
```

When I do :

```
MyData.iloc[-2]
```

It returns :

```
Name: 1, dtype: object
Date                2022-01-21
Unnamed: 0             Blablab
Unnamed: 1              WWWWWW
Unnamed: 2    123456789.123456
Co             33333333.333333
Ca               555555.555555
```

How would I get the below output :

```
1  2022-01-21               Blablab  ...  33333333.333333  555555.555555
```

I tried :

```
MyData.iloc[-2].T
```

But it is still in the same format ... What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Somehow I don't understand your question - do you want to have all the records in one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iloc[i]` returns a `Series`, which outputs as you showed. You want to output it in the way `DataFrame` is output. It so happens that `.iloc[i:j]` is a `DataFrame`. Just make it a one-row one:

```
MyData.iloc[-2:-2+1]
```

Comment: Thank you, I am new to it so what would it be for the third row ? `MyData.iloc[-3:-2+2]` ?

Answer (score 1):

This displays the row as you need it:

```
df.iloc[-2].to_frame().T
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're encountering here is that when you use iloc. to isolate a row, it's being returned as a series (not a dataframe).

Whatever it is you're wanting to do with this information, it may be best to leave it as a [series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784192/creating-an-empty-pandas-dataframe-then-filling-it).