# Convert Nested JSON to Pandas Dataframe (with JSON example)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON blob which looks like this:

```
    {'status': 'OK',
 'data-availability': 'available',
 'data': [{'page': 1, 'pages': 1, 'total': 7},
  [{'domain_id': '101',
    'domain_name': 'Province1',
    'domain_url': 'https://province1.com'},
   {'domain_id': '102',
    'domain_name': 'Province2',
    'domain_url': 'https://province2.com'},
   {'domain_id': '103',
    'domain_name': 'Province3',
    'domain_url': 'https://province3.com'},
   {'domain_id': '104',
    'domain_name': 'Province4',
    'domain_url': 'https://province4.com'},
   {'domain_id': '105',
    'domain_name': 'Province5',
    'domain_url': 'https://province5.com'},
   {'domain_id': '106',
    'domain_name': 'Province6',
    'domain_url': 'https://province6.com'},
   {'domain_id': '107',
    'domain_name': 'Province7',
    'domain_url': 'https://province7.com'}]]}
```

What I want is to normalize it into Pandas DataFrame which column are consist of domain_id, domain_name, and domain_url.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

[Repeated appending to a dataframe is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56746204/17769815). Instead, collect everything in a dictionary and then call `.from_dict()`:

```py
from pandas import pd

result = defaultdict(list)
for entry in data['data'][1]:
    for key, value in entry.items():
        result[key].append(value)

print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result))
```

This outputs:

```py
  domain_id domain_name             domain_url
0       101   Province1  https://province1.com
1       102   Province2  https://province2.com
2       103   Province3  https://province3.com
3       104   Province4  https://province4.com
4       105   Province5  https://province5.com
5       106   Province6  https://province6.com
6       107   Province7  https://province7.com
```

Comment: Thanks man! I learnt something new today!

Answer (score 0):

This does the job,

```
data = json.loads(test)["data"][-1]
df = pd.DataFrame()

for d in data:
  temp_df = pd.DataFrame([data[0]])
  df = pd.concat([df, temp_df])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pd.json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html).

```
raw_data = [{'domain_id': '101',
    'domain_name': 'Province1',
    'domain_url': 'https://province1.com'},
   {'domain_id': '102',
    'domain_name': 'Province2',
    'domain_url': 'https://province2.com'},
   {'domain_id': '103',
    'domain_name': 'Province3',
    'domain_url': 'https://province3.com'},
   {'domain_id': '104',
    'domain_name': 'Province4',
    'domain_url': 'https://province4.com'},
   {'domain_id': '105',
    'domain_name': 'Province5',
    'domain_url': 'https://province5.com'},
   {'domain_id': '106',
    'domain_name': 'Province6',
    'domain_url': 'https://province6.com'},
   {'domain_id': '107',
    'domain_name': 'Province7',
    'domain_url': 'https://province7.com'}]

# store data as df
df = pd.DataFrame({'raw':raw_data})

# split dict into columns with keys as column names
df_json = pd.json_normalize(df['raw'])

# concat dfs
df = pd.concat([df, df_json], axis=1)

# display
display(df)
```