# Python: How to append individual dictionaries to Series data structure

Tags: python, dictionary, append, typeerror, series

My goal is to create an output that has a Series datatype and following output:

[image]

I tried to achieve this by using the code below:

```
series_structure = pd.Series()

for i in table_dtypes[0]:
    if i == "object":
        type_dict = {'type': 'categorical'}
        series_structure.append(type_dict)
    elif i == "boolean":
        type_dict = {'type': 'boolean'}
        series_structure.append(type_dict)
    elif i == "datetime64": # revisit here 
        type_dict = {'type': 'datetime', 'format': '%Y-%m-%d'}
        series_structure.append(type_dict)
    elif i == "int64":
        type_dict = {'type': 'id', 'subtype': 'integer'}
        series_structure.append(type_dict)
    elif i == "float64": # revisit here 
        type_dict = {'type': 'numerical', 'subtype': 'float'}
        series_structure.append(type_dict)
```

But I get the error below:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

For reference my input dataset looks like this (table_dtypes):
[image]

What can I do?

Comment: I think your expected output should have `{'type': 'id', 'subtype': 'integer'}` at index `0` and `1`, no? Given: `elif i == "int64": \ type_dict = {'type': 'id', 'subtype': 'integer'}`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to confuse [`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) with [`Series.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html). As per the documentation: the latter expects a "Series or list/tuple of Series", hence the error. Apart from that, (1) the method is deprecated, and (2) "growing" a `df` or `Series` row-wise is generally an ill-advised practice (see this [`post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784192/creating-an-empty-pandas-dataframe-and-then-filling-it)).

One remedy could be to append to a `list`, and then use it as input for [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), as suggested in the [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74269083/18470692) by [`Z Li`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14751619/z-li).

Perhaps a better approach would be to get rid of the entire loop, and simply create a `dict` with the values from your `if/elif-statements` as keys, and the appropriate `dicts` as values. You can then simply use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to achieve the desired result. E.g.:

```
my_dict = {'object': {'type': 'categorical'},
           'booolean': {'type': 'boolean'},
           'datetime64': {'type': 'datetime', 'format': '%Y-%m-%d'},
           'int64': {'type': 'id', 'subtype': 'integer'},
           'float64': {'type': 'numerical', 'subtype': 'float'}}

series_structure = table_dtypes[0].map(my_dict)

print(series_structure)

0    {'type': 'id', 'subtype': 'integer'}
1    {'type': 'id', 'subtype': 'integer'}
2                 {'type': 'categorical'}
3                 {'type': 'categorical'}
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `pd.Series` at the end of the loop, which should also be faster:

```
series_structure = []

for i in table_dtypes[0]:
    if i == "object":
        type_dict = {'type': 'categorical'}
        series_structure.append(type_dict)
    # ...

series_structure = pd.Series(series_structure)
```