# How should you name columns when transposing a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I am initialising a dataframe with lists, having followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784192/creating-an-empty-pandas-dataframe-and-then-filling-it). I then need to transpose the dataframe.

In the first example I take the column names from the lists used to initialise the dataframe.

In the second example I add the column names last.

-> Is there any difference between these examples?

-> Is there a standard or better way of naming columns of dataframes initialised like this?

```
p_id = ['a_1','a_2']
p = ['a','b']
p_id.insert(0,'p_id')
p.insert(0,'p')

df = pd.DataFrame([p_id, p])
df = df.transpose()
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df

>>>
    p_id    p
0   a_1     a
1   a_2     b
```

```
p_id = ['a_1','a_2']
p = ['a','b']

df = pd.DataFrame([p_id, p])
df = df.transpose()
df.columns = ['p_id', 'p']
df

>>>
    p_id    p
0   a_1     a
1   a_2     b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is difference in indices:

```
print(df.equals(df1))
False

print (df.index)
RangeIndex(start=1, stop=3, step=1)

print (df1.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)

print (df.index == df1.index)
[False False]
```

Solution is create defaul index in `df` by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` parameter:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

print(df.equals(df1))
True

print (df.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)

print (df1.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)

print (df.index == df1.index)
[ True  True]
```

Comment: Thanks. So when using a list of lists to initialise a df, either way of naming columns is fine, so long as I correct the index? Obviously my second example is neater and preferable, but I wanted to illustrate the point in the first example.

Comment: @doine best is use `df = pd.DataFrame([p_id, p], index=['p_id', 'p']). transpose()` then is converted index to columns after transpose.