# How do I combine dataframes in a loop if not by pd.concat()?

Tags: python, pandas

I just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784192/creating-an-empty-pandas-dataframe-and-then-filling-it), where the top answer by user cs95 very clearly explains why creating an empty dataframe and appending to it is a bad idea, due to its memory usage. However, I unfortunately don't really understand how to do it in a better way. Here's what I'm working with:

I have 13 long-format csv files, which are hierarchical (each category has 2 sub-categories, which each have 3 sub-sub-categories, which each have another 3 sub-sub-sub-categories). I need to concatenate them. All the locations of the csv files are stored in the list `filepaths`.

What can I do instead of this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in filepaths:
   df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_csv(i)])
```

Comment: `df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(i) for i in filepaths])`