# import multiple XML files into one excel workbook in different individual sheets by python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, xml

I want to import 20 XML files into one excel file as 20 individual worksheets.

The structure of these XML files are the same, just the values are different.
[This is how the XML file looks like. I only need the X and Y values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL5CV.png)

My idea is to import the data that I need (the values of X and Y) into python first and make a table, then import the table into an excel file.

I started from importing one XML file and make one table in python. Here is the code that I wrote:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

file_path = file_path
root = ET.parse(file_path).getroot()
for Point in root.findall('Point'):
    X = float(Point.find('X').text)
    Y = float(Point.find('Y').text)
    kraft_all = [Y]
    data = {'Weg/mm': [X], 'Kraft/N': [Y],'Max. Kraft/N':max(kraft_all)}
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    print(df)
```

[What I got looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0l5O.png)

My questions are:

1. Why does each value have a corresponding column name? How to show the column names only in the first row?
2. How to get the maximum value from Y values and write it in the first 'cell' of the third column 'Max. Kraft/N'?

Before, I only have tried to import multiple CSV files into an excel file through **pd.read_csv** and **df.to_excel** and it succeeded. So, after solving the first 2 questions, I can try to deal with multiple files by myself. But maybe someone could give me some advice already :)

Thanks for your time!

---

**Update_2023.10.09**

I changed my code according to @Edo Akse and add some codes to import the dataframe into an excel file. It worked out for one xml file :). Here is the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

file_path = r'C:\Users\xli\OneDrive - TFI Aachen GmbH\Excel_Beige und Weiß_Tru\tru Beige\tru beige-1.xml'
root = ET.parse(file_path).getroot()
as_list = []
for Point in root.findall("Point"):
    X = float(Point.find("X").text)
    Y = float(Point.find("Y").text)
    line = {"Weg/mm": X, "Kraft/N": Y}
    as_list.append(line)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(as_list)
print(df)
excel_path = r'C:\Users\xli\OneDrive - TFI Aachen GmbH\Excel_Beige und Weiß_Tru\beige.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_path,engine='openpyxl')
df.to_excel(excel_writer=writer,sheet_name='tru beige-1')
writer.close()
```

Now I want to

1. import multiple xml files from one folder to multiple dataframes
2. import the dataframes into multiple sheets in one excel file

I referred to @Hermann12. My code is here:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os
from pathlib import Path

def load_xml(files):
    column = ["Weg[mm]","Kraft[N]"]
    df1 = pd.concat([pd.read_xml(file, names=column) for file in files])
    return df1

excel_path = r'C:\Users\xli\OneDrive - TFI Aachen GmbH\Excel_Beige und Weiß_Tru\beige.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_path,engine='openpyxl')
num=1
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\xli\OneDrive - TFI Aachen GmbH\Excel_Beige und Weiß_Tru\tru Beige"):
    print(root)
    print(dirs)
    print(files)
    for file in files:
        xml_files = Path(r"C:\Users\xli\OneDrive - TFI Aachen GmbH\Excel_Beige und Weiß_Tru\tru Beige").glob('*.xml') 
        df = load_xml(xml_files)
        df.to_excel(excel_writer=writer,sheet_name=file)
    writer.close()
```

There is a **ValueError: names does not match length of child elements in xpath**.

Can anyone have a look at my codes and change the wrong places?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have we not heard about [**`pandas.read_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is with this section:

```py
    kraft_all = [Y]
    data = {'Weg/mm': [X], 'Kraft/N': [Y],'Max. Kraft/N':max(kraft_all)}
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    print(df)
```

Since this is inside the for loop, in each iteration of the loop, you're overwriting the variables `kraft_all`, `data` and `df`, which means that at the end of the loop, all of them only contain the last assigned value.

What you want to do instead is to append to the variables.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56746204/9267296) the correct way to build a df is to create a list first and then turn that into a df.

As for getting the max, it's not advised to store a max for a column in each row, as you're basically storing the same value each time. Best is to just get the value when needed, or after loading the df.

Combining this, I got to the code below:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

file_path = "tst.xml"
root = ET.parse(file_path).getroot()

as_list = []
for Point in root.findall("Point"):
    X = float(Point.find("X").text)
    Y = float(Point.find("Y").text)
    line = {"Weg/mm": X, "Kraft/N": Y}
    as_list.append(line)


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(as_list)

m = max(df["Kraft/N"])
print(m)
print(df)
```

output:

```
42.0
   Weg/mm  Kraft/N
0     1.0      5.0
1     2.0      4.0
2     3.0     42.0
3     4.0     11.0
4     5.0     11.0
```

I used the XML below:

```xml
<Measurement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Point>
        <X>1</X>
        <Y>5</Y>
        <UnitX>mm</UnitX>
        <UnitY>N</UnitY>
    </Point>
    <Point>
        <X>2</X>
        <Y>4</Y>
        <UnitX>mm</UnitX>
        <UnitY>N</UnitY>
    </Point>
    <Point>
        <X>3</X>
        <Y>42</Y>
        <UnitX>mm</UnitX>
        <UnitY>N</UnitY>
    </Point>
    <Point>
        <X>4</X>
        <Y>11</Y>
        <UnitX>mm</UnitX>
        <UnitY>N</UnitY>
    </Point>
    <Point>
        <X>5</X>
        <Y>11</Y>
        <UnitX>mm</UnitX>
        <UnitY>N</UnitY>
    </Point>
</Measurement>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you share the XML not as picture we can use it for explanation.
I would do this in pandas, if all xml files in the folder of the py script:

```
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

def load_xml(files):
    column = ["Weg[mm]","Kraft[N]","Unit X","Unit Y"]
    df1 = pd.concat([pd.read_xml(file, names=column) for file in files])
    res = df1.sort_values('Kraft[N]', ascending=False)
    return res
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xml_files = [f for f in pathlib.Path().glob("*.xml")]
    df = load_xml(xml_files)
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Weg[mm]  Kraft[N] Unit X Unit Y
2     3.00     42.00     mm      N
3     4.00     11.00     mm      N
4     5.00     11.00     mm      N
0     1.00      5.45     mm      N
1     2.00      4.00     mm      N
5    19.29      0.25     mm      N
   ...
```

Comment: Consider list comprehension and avoid the bookkeeping of appending to a list in loop: `df1 = pd.concat([pd.read_xml(file) for file in files])`