# Creating new row from columns in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
hiring_mgr_id   candidate_id      candidate_name       emp_id       emp_name
    1000            1234               Joe                4321        Mike
    1000            1234               Joe                9876        Sam
    1000            1234               Joe                5674        Rob
```

what I want is to create a new row grouping by `hiring_mgr_id` and if the `candidate_id` is not in the `emp_id` column then create a new row with populating `emp_id` and  `emp_name`.

What I want:

```
 hiring_mgr_id      candidatae_id      candidate_name      emp_id    emp_name
     1000                1234                Joe            4321        Mike
     1000                1234                Joe            9876        Sam
     1000                1234                Joe            5674        Rob
     1000                1234                Joe            1234        Joe
```

So far this is what I have:

```
new_row = [] 
for index, row  in df.iterrows():
    candidate_id= row['candidate_id']
    emp_id = row['emp_id']
    if candidate_id not in df['emp_id'].values:
       new_row.append({'hiring_mgr_id:row['hiring_mg'r_id],
       'candidate_name':row['candidate_name'],
       'emp_id':row['emp_id'],
       'emp_name': row['emp_name']
df = df.append(new_row,ignore_index = True)
```

When I do this I get an error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'

I thought you could use append with DataFrames any suggestion on how to fix? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would advise reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784192/creating-an-empty-pandas-dataframe-and-then-filling-it

Comment: This is good information thank you for sharing the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, which is based on the idea of creating a new dataframe with the 3 first columns and duplicating the `candidate_id` and `candidate_name` columns. Then, the two dataframes are concatenated and the duplicates dropped:

```
pd.concat([
    df,
    df.iloc[:, :3].assign(emp_id = 
                          df['candidate_id'],
                          emp_name = df['candidate_name'])])
.drop_duplicates()
```