What does "DataFrame.at[source]: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" mean?
Searching for answers to "dataframe. at TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" resulted in "We couldn't find anything for dataframe. at typeerror: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index".
Searching with less stringent rules produced results that required me to search those for ".at" produced nothing either. Of course, that could be due to my search terms.
Can anyone explain precisely what this means in terms that a non-programmer can understand?

"property DataFrame.at[source]: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays
can be converted to a scalar index"

The pandas website states the following:

pandas.DataFrame.at property DataFrame.at[source] Access a single
value for a row/column label pair.

That seems obvious and thus easy to use. However, the following code snippit:
col = str(currentyr)
print('col = ' + str(col))
row = str(currentmonth) + 'UTtotal'
print('row = ' + str(row))
DTduration = df_total.at[row, col]
print('row / col (' + str(row) + ' / ' + str(col) + ') =\n' + str(DTduration))

generates the following error:
"TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 269
    266     monthlyUT()
    268     #deal with monthly downtimes
--> 269     monthlyDT(faultindexfirst, faultindexlast)
    271     framenum += 1
    273 elif framestartyear == currentyr & frameendyear == currentyr + 1:
    274         #the currently selected frame straddles two years

Cell In[1], line 46
     44     print('row = ' + str(row))
     45 #    DTduration = df_total.loc[row, col]
---> 46     DTduration = df_total.at[row, col]
     47     print('row / col (' + str(row) + ' / ' + str(col) + ') =\n' + str(DTduration))
     48     row = str(currentmonth) + 'Eventstotal'"

faultindexfirst, faultindexlast, currentyr and currentmonth are all integers. I am trying to access a specific datum in a dataframe:
                      2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023  \
UTtotal        2311.933333  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
DTtotal                NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
Eventstotal            NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
1UTtotal               NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
1DTtotal               NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
1Eventstotal           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
.
.
.
11Eventstotal          NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
12UTtotal              NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
12DTtotal              NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
12Eventstotal          NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   

In this case, I need to populate this table with valid data but the pandas site provides no information that I understand enough to resolve this error. The print statements successfully out the following:
col = 2013
row = 9UTtotal

Minimally Reproducible Example:
import pandas
import os
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import matplotlib.dates as mdates
#from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from datetime import date
from datetime import time
from datetime import datetime
import array

def monthlyDT(firstidx, lastidx):
    #this routine handles the monthly downtime data totaling and copying to the table
    print('entered downtimes()')
    print('\tthe first downtime timestamp = ' + str(DTs[firstidx]))
    print('\tthe last downtime timestamp = ' + str(DTs[lastidx]))
    
    #retrieve the current monthly DT duration and number of events totals from the table
    print('row indices:\n' + str(df_total.index))
    print('column headers: \n' + str(df_total.columns))

    col = str(currentyr)
    print('col = ' + str(col))
    row = str(currentmonth) + 'UTtotal'
    print('row = ' + str(row))
    DTduration = df_total.at[row, col]
    print('row / col (' + str(row) + ' / ' + str(col) + ') =\n' + str(DTduration))
    return()


#setup working arrays to hold the datasets
DTs = np.array([1.378854180000000000e+09, 1.378904520000000000e+09, 1.378957920000000000e+09, 1.378968180000000000e+09])
DTe = np.array([1.378858140000000000e+09, 1.378908000000000000e+09, 1.378958040000000000e+09, 1.378968240000000000e+09])

#build the 'year' column names array
colname = []
y = 2013
currentyr = 2013
yrend = 2024
currentmonth = 9
while y <= yrend:
    colname.append(str(y))
    y = y + 1
print('colname = ' + str(colname))
#create the index name array
indexnames = ['UTtotal', 'DTtotal', 'Eventstotal', 
            '1UTtotal', '1DTtotal', '1Eventstotal',
            '2UTtotal', '2DTtotal', '2Eventstotal',
            '3UTtotal', '3DTtotal', '3Eventstotal',
            '4UTtotal', '4DTtotal', '4Eventstotal',
            '5UTtotal', '5DTtotal', '5Eventstotal',
            '6UTtotal', '6DTtotal', '6Eventstotal',
            '7UTtotal', '7DTtotal', '7Eventstotal',
            '8UTtotal', '8DTtotal', '8Eventstotal',
            '9UTtotal', '9DTtotal', '9Eventstotal',
            '10UTtotal', '10DTtotal', '10Eventstotal',
            '11UTtotal', '11DTtotal', '11Eventstotal',
            '12UTtotal', '12DTtotal', '12Eventstotal'
            ]

#create dataframe
df_total = pandas.DataFrame(columns=[colname], index=[indexnames], dtype=np.float64)
print('df_total is:\n' + str(df_total))
df_total = df_total.fillna(-1)
print('\n\ndf_total is:\n' + str(df_total) + '\n\n')

monthlyDT(0, 3)
print('end')


The existing pandas documentation is not complete enough. For example, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784192/creating-an-empty-pandas-dataframe-and-then-filling-it. The 'NEVER grow a DataFrame row-wise!' answer states: 'And then, there's creating a DataFrame of NaNs, and all the caveats associated therewith.' but the pandas.DataFrame constructor page provides no caveat(s), but it does mention 'NaN'. I will continue hacking, but would like to understand why .at throws that error.

It would be useful to provide [MRE].

Vitalizzare, I added some minimal code that creates the same result, that error message.

This was caused by a very innocuous typo.  In this line:
df_total = pandas.DataFrame(columns=[colname], index=[indexnames], dtype=np.float64)

colname and indexnames are already lists.  You have made them into lists of lists, which makes both the column and row headers into a multiindex.  Just remove the brackets:
df_total = pandas.DataFrame(columns=colname, index=indexnames, dtype=np.float64)


Tim, you are brilliant! However, I do not find the error message helpful, but with your clear explanation I can see what it is referring to. Situations like this help me interpret what are otherwise very cryptic messages. Thanks!
