# How to add an extra row to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

If I have an empty dataframe as such:

```
columns = ['Date', 'Name', 'Action','ID']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

Is there a way to append a new row to this newly created dataframe? Currently I have to create a dictionary, populate it, then append the dictionary to the dataframe at the end. Is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Upcoming pandas 0.13 version will allow to add rows through `loc` on non existing index data. However, be aware that under the hood, this creates a copy of the entire DataFrame so it is not an efficient operation.

Description is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) and this new feature is called *Setting With Enlargement*.

Comment: enlargement only allowed thru ``loc`` (``iloc`` could add not-at-the-end so its a bit ambiguous)

Comment: typo, corrected, thanks.

Comment: I played around with doing this on an empty DataFrame, and I found that it did not work. Seems to work only if the frame has at least one row....

Comment: not cool for the completeness of pandas apis...

Comment: @DanAllan why don't u post an issue on github with some examples

Comment: [Done.](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5226)

Comment: this is fixed in master see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5226). @Boud always welcome bug reports and/or PR's for new features which are not always complete the second they are out.

Comment: I've found that this will drop any columns from the added Series that are not already in the DataFrame. In this case, the documentation is misleading in that it states that "Setting With Enlargement" is like an "append" operation, even though "append" will add any new columns to the DataFrame.

Comment: Isn't this a lot slower than creating a dictionary and then adding the entire dictionary to `df`?

Comment: Isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32749104/938408) how it is supposed to work? Then why doesn't it?

Answer (score 117):

Try this:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = ['8/19/2014', 'Jun', 'Fly', '98765']
```

Warning: this method works only if there are no "holes" in the index. For example, suppose you have a DataFrame with three rows, with indices 0, 1, and 3 (for example, because you deleted row number 2). Then, len(df) = 3, so by the above command does not add a new row - it overrides row number 3.

Comment: `df.loc[df.shape[0]]` (even `df.loc[len(df.index)]`) is much faster than `df.loc[len(df)]`.

Comment: one element
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : len(flows))
2.4147243930055993
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : flows.shape[0])
3.4786632809991715

4k elements:
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : len(flows))
2.520429938987945
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : flows.shape[0])
3.6195146050013136

Comment: If you're using `len(df)`, why do we use `loc` instead of `iloc`?  Doesn't it have the danger of matching a member of the index, rather than a row number?

Comment: Goodness, this took a long time to figure out! Much appreciated!

Comment: This is an INCREDIBLY SLOW method of appending a row to a dataframe. As a practical example, I created a dataframe from parsing a file have 1.5 million lines using this method and it took over 7 hours. The same thing when done with a dictionary and then put into a dataframe took about 10 seconds. This internally happens because of the slow appending to a Series. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37992805/1224075 for understanding what happens internally.

Comment: Most intuitive I have found, even if slow...

Comment: If it works and it's slow, it still works.

Answer (score 5):

A different approach that I found ugly compared to the classic dict+append, but that works:

```
df = df.T

df[0] = ['1/1/2013', 'Smith','test',123]

df = df.T

df
Out[6]: 
       Date   Name Action   ID
0  1/1/2013  Smith   test  123
```