# getting pandas Setting With Enlargement right

Tags: python, pandas

Since version 0.13, it is possible to append to a dataframe by referring to indices in .loc or .ix which are not yet in the dataframe. See the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement).

Then I am confused why this line fails:

```
all_treatments.loc[originalN:newN,:]    = all_treatments.loc[0:newrowcount,:]
```

This generates a ValueError:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (12) into shape (0)
```

Here `all_treatments.shape = (53, 12)`, `originalN = 53`, `newN = 64`, `all_treatments.loc[originalN:newN,:].shape = (0,12)`, `all_treatments.loc[0:newrowcount,:].shape = (12,12)`.

What is the proper way to set with enlargement here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only set by enlargement with a single row or column. You are setting with a range.

> The .loc/.ix/[] operations can perform enlargement when setting a non-existant **key** for that axis.

For your use, something like this should work to expand a dataframe with new blank rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
>>> df
    a   b
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6

new_row_count = 2
for new_row, old_row in enumerate(range(new_row_count), start=len(df)):
    df.ix[new_row] = None

>>>df
    a   b
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6
3   NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN
```

If you wanted to copy data from the original dataframe, I would normally just concatenate.

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.iloc[:2, :]], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Great, I'll accept this in a second, but can you perhaps help with adding `newrowcount` new rows to an existing dataframe? They could be empty, though I tried to copy the first `newrowcount` rows not to hassle with NaN or NaT or string issues. I understand this is not the exact topic of the question.

Comment: The iteration sounds inefficient (I have many rows to add), but the concatenation is a great answer, should have thought of it! Thanks!