# Add row to dataframe syntax issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a new row to the dataframe `df` based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701570/adding-rows-to-empty-dataframe-with-columns) but I'm getting the syntax wrong. What am I missing?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['poll1', 'poll2','tval','pval'])
temp = pd.DataFrame([0,0,1,2], columns=['poll1', 'poll2','tval','pval'])
df.append(temp)
print(df)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['poll1', 'poll2','tval','pval'], data=[[0,0,1,2]])
print(df)
```

or if you want to use append:

```
cols = ['poll1', 'poll2','tval','pval']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
temp = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0,0,1,2]], columns = cols)
df = df.append(temp)
print(df)
```