# How to add new line to existing pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has been defined as empty and then I would like to add some rows to it after doing some calculations.

I have tried to do the following:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Gender'])

if #some statement:

test.append(['James', '95', 'M'])
```

If I try to print and then append to test shows

```
print(test)

test.append(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'])

print(test)

>>>

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, Age, Gender]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, Age, Gender]
Index: []
```

So clearly the line is not being added to the dataframe.

I want the output to be

```
Name | Age | Gender
James | 95 | M
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `append` with dictionary as:

```
test = test.append(dict(zip(test.columns,['James', '95', 'M'])), ignore_index=True)

print(test)
    Name Age Gender
0  James  95      M
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass as a [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html):

```
test.append(pd.Series(['James', 95, 'M'], index=test.columns), ignore_index=True)
```

[out]

```
    Name Age Gender
0  James  95      M
```

Comment: Will give it a try, do you know how efficient this would be compared to the loc method that is in pandas version 0.13 and above described here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365513/how-to-add-an-extra-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe/19368360#19368360

Comment: `append` is generally more computationally expensive than other operations -  `concat` for example. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) it may be better to append the new rows to a list, then use `concat`, than to append many rows iteratively.

Answer (score 1):

Try to append it as dictionary:

```
>>> test = test.append({'Name': "James", "Age": 95, "Gender": "M"}, ignore_index=True)
>>> print(test)
```

Outputs:

```
    Name Age Gender
0  James  95      M
```

Comment: Will give it a try, do you know how efficient this would be compared to the loc method that is in pandas version 0.13 and above described here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365513/how-to-add-an-extra-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe/19368360#19368360

Answer (score 1):

**Append function will convert list into DataFrame,it automatic generation columns[0],but test have columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Gender'].And append Will not change test.What I said may be confusing,running the following code might make you understand.**

```
import pandas as pd

#Append function will convert list into DataFrame,and two dataframe object should have the same column
data = pd.DataFrame(['James', '95', 'M'])
print(data)

#right code
test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Gender'])
test = test.append(pd.DataFrame([['James', '95', 'M']],columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Gender']))
print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, the `append` method does not modify the `DataFrame` in place but returns the modified (appended version).

**Second**, the new row passed should be either a `DataFrame`, either a `dict`/`Series`, or either a list of these.

```py
#using dict
row = {'Name': "James", "Age": 95, "Gender": "M"}
# using Series
row = pd.Series(['James', 95, 'M'], index=test.columns))
```

Try `print( test.append(row) )` and see the result.

What you need is to save the return value of `test.append` as the appended version, you can save it with the same name if you don't care about the preceding version, it gives us:

```py
test = test.append( row )
```

Comment: I tried this and it adds each one as a new row so it gives James, 95, M going down the name column with the rest blanks.

Comment: Yes, I forgot you need to pass a `Dataframe` or dict or `Series` instead of just a list, I modified the answer to make it complete using other ones' suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
>>> test.append(dict(zip(test.columns,['James', '95', 'M'])), ignore_index=True)

    Name Age Gender
0  James  95      M
```