# Add item to pandas.Series?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I want to add an integer to my `pandas.Series`
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
input = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
input.append(6)
```

When i run this, i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    f.append(6)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2047, in append
    verify_integrity=verify_integrity)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 878, in concat
    verify_integrity=verify_integrity)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 954, in __init__
    self.new_axes = self._get_new_axes()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 1146, in _get_new_axes
    concat_axis = self._get_concat_axis()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 1163, in _get_concat_axis
    indexes = [x.index for x in self.objs]
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 1163, in <listcomp>
    indexes = [x.index for x in self.objs]
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'index'
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a single item to a Pandas Series](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331518/how-to-add-a-single-item-to-a-pandas-series)

Comment: None of these questions are mine. Also, your question was asked 12 months ago, but the one I linked to was asked over two years ago.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Convert appended item to `Series`:

```
>>> ds = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5]) 
>>> ds.append(pd.Series([6]))
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
0    6
dtype: int64
```

or use `DataFrame`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(ds)
>>> df.append([6], ignore_index=True)
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
```

and last option if your index is without gaps,

```
>>> ds.set_value(max(ds.index) + 1,  6)
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
dtype: int64
```

And you can use numpy as a last resort:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> pd.Series(np.concatenate((ds.values, [6])))
```

Comment: as of today, .set_value() is deprecated, use .at()/.iat() instead

Comment: As Comte says, set_value deprecated. See Gormoruk's answer for the correct solution. (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.at.html#pandas.Series.at)

Comment: Note that `append` is now [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append) and has been removed in pandas 2.0.0, [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) could be used as replacement.

Comment: As `append` is deprecated from pandas 2.0.0, we can use `_append`.
e.g. - `ds._append(pd.Series([6]))`

Answer (score 5):

Using `set_value` generates the warning:

> FutureWarning: set_value is deprecated and will be removed in a future
> release. Please use .at[] or .iat[] accessors instead

So you can instead use `at` like this:

```
input.at[input.index[-1]+1]=6
```

Answer (score 4):

#### For Pandas >= 2.0:

`series.append(s)` was [Deprecated since version 1.4.0.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html)
Removed since version 2.0 ([2.0.0 (April 3, 2023)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/2.0/whatsnew/index.html))

Recommended approach is [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

#### Series + Series:

```py
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series([False, False, False], index=[1,0,2] )
s2 = pd.Series( True )

pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
>>>
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool

pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=0)
>>>
1    False
0    False
2    False
0     True
dtype: bool
```

#### DF + Series:

Adding to a series already in a df, becomes DF + DF: (note the indexing and column rename)

```
_df = pd.DataFrame( s1, columns=['a'] )
_df
>>>
    a
1   False
0   False
2   False

pd.concat([ _df, 
            s2.to_frame().T.rename({0:'a'},axis=1)
           ], 
           ignore_index=True)
>>>
    a
0   False
1   False
2   False
3   True
```

Answer (score -1):

**here is a one-line answer** It is dependent on how the array is defined. If we use Series is a one d array. Use the array notation like x[index] = new value

example

```
import pandas as pd
input = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
newval = 7 # say
input[len(input)] = newval
```

or 
use append if the array is being directly defined.

```
#if input is defined as []
input2 = [1, 2]
#input2[len(input2)] = 3 # does not work
input2.append(3) #works
input2
```