# How to merge two pandas series & keep repeated values

Tags: python, pandas, merge, time-series, series

I have two pandas series data as `

```
2732     5.347656
10799    4.671875
9845     4.882812
3264     4.492188
13123    5.253906
4859     5.320312
9225     2.947266
7891     3.464844
4373     2.398438
5874     3.951172
```

&

```
3875     2.468750
6688     2.501953
7193     6.097656
2732     5.347656
11157    6.300781
12020    3.777344
4859     5.320312
5350     4.710938
8820     2.388672
5874     3.951172
```

I want to stack these two series vertically but I want to keep the repeating columns intact & they should be repeating in the stacked series.

Required Output:-

```
2732     5.347656
10799    4.671875
9845     4.882812
3264     4.492188
13123    5.253906
4859     5.320312
9225     2.947266
7891     3.464844
4373     2.398438
5874     3.951172
3875     2.468750
6688     2.501953
7193     6.097656
2732     5.347656
11157    6.300781
12020    3.777344
4859     5.320312
5350     4.710938
8820     2.388672
5874     3.951172
```

Comment: See if this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441980/add-item-to-pandas-series

Comment: `s.append(s1)` should do it.

Comment: I think append works guys thanks a lot!!!