# Adding individual items and sequences of items to dataframes and series

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe `df`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

and I have the following tuple and value:

```
column_and_row = ('bar', 'foo')
value = 56
```

How can I most easily **add** this tuple to my dataframe so that:

```
df['bar']['foo']
```

returns `56`?

What if I have a list of such tuples and list of values?  e.g.

```
columns_and_rows = [A, B, C, ...]
values = [5, 10, 15]
```

where `A`, `B` and `C` are tuples of columns and rows (similar to `column_and_row`).

Along the same lines, how would this be done with a `Series`?, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
srs = pd.Series()
```

and I want to **add** one item to it with index `'foo'` and value `2` so that:

```
srs['foo']
```

returns `2`?

**Note:**
I know that **none** of these are efficient ways of creating `dataframes` or `series`, but I need a solution that allows me to grow my structures organically in this way when I have no other choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a series, you can do it with `append`, but you have to create a series from your value first:

```
>>> print x
A    1
B    2
C    3
>>> print x.append( pandas.Series([8, 9], index=["foo", "bar"]))
A      1
B      2
C      3
foo    8
bar    9
```

For a DataFrame, you can also use `append` or `concat`, but it doesn't make sense to do this for a single cell only.  DataFrames are tabular, so you can only add a whole row or a whole column.  [The documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects) has plenty of examples and there are [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe) about this.

Edit: Apparently you actually can set a single value with `df.set_value('newRow', 'newCol', newVal)`.  However, if that row/column doesn't already exist, this will actually create an entire new row and/or column, with the rest of the values in the created row/column filled with NaN.  Note that in this case a new object will be returned, so you'd have to do `df = df.set_value('newRow', 'newCol', newVal)` to modify the original.

However, now matter how you do it, this is going to be inefficient.  Pandas data structures are based on Numpy and are fundamentally reliant on knowing the size of the array ahead of time.  You can add rows and columns, but every time you do so, and entirely new data structure is created, so if you do this a lot, it will be slower than using ordinary Python lists/dicts.

Comment: Thanks. Even if it's inefficient, how can I easily add a single element to a DataFrame?

Comment: @user815423426: As I said in the post, you can't.  You can only add a row or a column.

Comment: df.set_value(row,column,value) in 0.10.1

Comment: @Jeff: Interesting, I didn't realize `set_value` supported setting indices that don't already exist.  I updated my answer.