# Pandas: Moving from table to matrix layout

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like (it's a set of combinations):

```
   A  B  C  
a  1  1  3  
b  1  2  4  
c  2  1  5  
d  2  2  6
```

Which I would like to transform into a matrix where the new columns and indexes are unique values of two of the columns (`A` and `B`) and the cells are the join between these two unique values from a third column (`C`).

With `A` as the index, `B` as the columns and `C` as the cell values I would have something like:

```
   B
A  1 2
1  3 4  
2  5 6
```

To generate this new 'matrix' DataFrame I iteratively filter the original DF by the unique values in columns `A`, then get the `C` column as a Series, like:

```
for ind in unique_indexes: # made by using .drop_duplicates on the column
    rows = original_table[(original_table['A'] == ind)] 
    new_series = rows['C']
```

I'm then trying to glue all of these Series together as rows in a new DataFrame, but can't get any of them to either `append` or `concat` into the new DataFrame (following both the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) or [similar questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe)), e.g.

```
# with suitable placement in 'for' loop
df = DataFrame()
df.append(new_series)

>>> print df
Empty DataFrame
```

Is there a) a better way of doing this transformation, or b) a step that I'm missing in appending series to a DataFrame?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to make a `pivot_table`, like this?

```
>>> df
   A  B  C
a  1  1  3
b  1  2  4
c  2  1  5
d  2  2  6
>>> pd.pivot_table(df, rows="A", cols="B", values="C")
B  1  2
A      
1  3  4
2  5  6
```

Comment: Cheers, the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) is very clear on my use case as well