# How to use a for loop to append the data frame generated from a function in python

Tags: python, pandas, append, scikit-learn

My question is I generated a function to store the 10-fold cross-validation scores for each of the stepwise models within each classifier. For example, for Naive Bayes, I have two models, one only use one variable but others use two. The similar to decision tree model. The function is something like

```
def crossV(clf):
    cvOutcome=pd.DataFrame()
    index=pd.DataFrame()
    classifier=pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(4)[2:]:
        tt=array(tuple(x[1:i] for x in modelDataFullnew))
        qq=array(tuple(x[0] for x in modelDataFullnew))
        scores=cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, tt, qq, cv=10)*100
        index_i=list(np.repeat(i-1,10))
        classifier_i=list(np.repeat(str(clf)[:-2],10))
        scores=list(scores)
        cvOutcome=cvOutcome.append(scores)
        index=index.append(index_i)
        classifier=classifier.append(classifier_i)
    merge=pd.concat([index,cvOutcome,classifier],axis=1)
    merge.columns=['model','rate','classifier']
    return(merge)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB as gnb
clf_nb=gnb()
from sklearn import tree
clf_dt=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

If I do `crossV(clf_nb)` it will give me the result as

```
    model   rate    classifier
   1     92.558679   GaussianNB
   1     92.558381   GaussianNB
   1     92.558381   GaussianNB
   1     92.558381   GaussianNB
   1     92.558381   GaussianNB
```

My question is how can I apply this function to several classifiers and append their result as a long data frame like

```
    model   rate    classifier
   1     92.558679   GaussianNB
   1     92.558381   GaussianNB
   1     92.558381   GaussianNB
   1     92.558381   GaussianNB
   1     92.558381   GaussianNB
   1     93.25       DecisionTree
   1     93.25       DecisionTree
```

i tried this code but it does not work:

```
hhh=[clf_nb,clf_dt]

g=pd.DataFrame()
while i in hhh:
    g=g.append(crossV(i))
```

I also tried map function in array like

```
map(crossV,(clf_nb,clf_dt))
```

It works but just give me a larger list and I don't know how to transform it to data frame.

Comment: possible duplicate of [add one row in a pandas.DataFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: I tried but the result is nothing I don't know what goes wrong here

Comment: Did you try `df = pd.concat( (crossV(clf_nb), crossV(clf_dt)) )`

Comment: this code worked but what if I have twenty classifiers? I want to write a general function to do that but it somehow did not work for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clf = [clf_nb, clf_dt]

cross_clf = [ crossV(x) for x in clf ]

df = pd.concat( cross_clf )
```

---

**EDIT:**

Example to your question in comment:

I need `i = clf_nb` or `i = clf_nb` to starts `while`

```
hhh = [clf_nb, clf_dt]

g = pd.DataFrame()

i = clf_nb

while i in hhh: # if `clf_nb` is still on the list `hhh` then ...
    g.append( crossV(i) ) # append `clf_nb` to the `g`
```

but `i` is all the time equils `clf_nb` and `clf_nb` is all the time on list `hhh` so you have endless loop which always add `clf_nb` to `g`

Comment: thanks! It works!!! But could you please point out why the while loop does not work here? Thanks again!

Comment: `while i in hhh` means: if value from `i` exists on list `hhh` than repeat. It is like `if i in hhh`.

Comment: Thanks! But I am still a little bit confused while `i` is in `hhh` why it does not do the concat or append as your code does? Thanks again!:)@furas

Comment: First you have no variable `i`, second `i` would have to be  `i = clf_nb` or `i = clf_dt`, third `in` in `for` works in different way than in `while` and `if`. `in` in `while` only check "if 'i' is still on list 'hhh' then ...", `in` in `for` do `get next element from 'hhh' and assign it to 'i' then ..."

Comment: I add some example to answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is much clear now but actually it is not endless loop but return a null result @furas

Comment: Because your `i` is not equile to `clf_nb` or `clf_dt` so `while i in hhh` gives `False` and `g.append()` is not executed. Try `print( i in hhh )`.