# 'Where clause' on a list in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having this kind of pandas Datamframe named df:

```
     email        | list
___________________________
email1@email.com  | [0,1]
email1@email.com  | [2,1]
email1@email.com  | [0,3]
email1@email.com  | [0,0]
email1@email.com  | [0,1]
```

I want to retrieve all the row from df having a 0 list : [0,0]

I'm doing:

```
df2 = df[df['list'] == [0,0]]
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 5 vs 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this is not working:

```
df2 = df[df['list'] == [0, 0]]
```

is because df['list'] is a 5 element long list, and `[0, 0]` is a two element long list. It fails while evaluating your mask

```
df['list'] == [0, 0]
```

#### Updated proper solution

I believe the fastest way of solving this is to create a series of [0,0] elements the length of your dataframe, and compare this series to your column

```
df['list'] == pd.Series([[0, 0]] * len(df))

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    True
4    False
```

This creates a mask by comparing each *element* in the list to `[0, 0]` instead of comparing the *list* `df['list']` to `[0, 0]`

Using this mask you can then create your new dataframe

```
mask = df['list'] == pd.Series([[0, 0]] * len(df))
df2 = df[mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

your comparing the list of lists to an individual entry. You should instead filter df by using `iterrows()`. `iterrows()` creates a generator whic yields tuples whose second entry is the dictionary of columns. you can iterate through them and match against them, then build a new dataframe.

```
df2 = {'email':[], 'list':[]}
for row in df.iterrows():
    row_dictionary = row[1]
    if row_dictionary['list'] == [0,0]:
        for key in df2.keys():
            df2[key].append(row_dictionary[key])
df2 = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(df2)
```

By using the dictionary's keys to populate it you can use this method on any dataframe.

Comment: thanks for the solution, but by looping in each row I'm scared I'm gonna lose a lot in term of complexity

Comment: In the specific case of two columns you won't, but you can also use dataframe.loc to directly input them into the new dataframe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe