# Appending a list or series to a pandas DataFrame as a row?

Tags: python, pandas, append, dataframe

So I have initialized an empty pandas DataFrame and I would like to iteratively append lists (or Series) as rows in this DataFrame. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Better answers can be found under: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Sometimes it's easier to do all the appending outside of pandas, then, just create the DataFrame in one shot.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> simple_list=[['a','b']]
>>> simple_list.append(['e','f'])
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(simple_list,columns=['col1','col2'])
   col1 col2
0    a    b
1    e    f
```

Comment: The question seems to imply that not all the rows are known up front.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question.

Answer (score 190):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list("ABC"))
df.loc[len(df)] = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: This is the easiest if you are looking to add to the end of the `df`.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, so simple yet effective!

Comment: Why is this not the selected answer?

Comment: This is generally ok but only works if you have a monotonically increasing index that started at 0.

Answer (score 71):

Here's a simple and dumb solution:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df = df.append({'foo':1, 'bar':2}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Note that this is appending a dict, not a list

Comment: Also note that pandas is going to remove df.append in near future. One should use pd.concat. I have written an answer with this suggestion

Answer (score 42):

Could you do something like this?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2'])
>>> df = df.append(pd.Series(['a', 'b'], index=['col1','col2']), ignore_index=True)
>>> df = df.append(pd.Series(['d', 'e'], index=['col1','col2']), ignore_index=True) 
>>> df
  col1 col2
0    a    b
1    d    e
```

Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Comment: Here's a simpler and dumb solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.append({'foo':1, 'bar':2}, ignore_index=True)
# Note that this appending doesn't happen in place.
```

Comment: The `index` parameter should probably be named `columns`; `ignore_index` here ignores the index - the name of the Series.

Answer (score 33):

Following onto Mike Chirico's answer...  if you want to append a list *after* the dataframe is already populated...

```
>>> list = [['f','g']]
>>> df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(list, columns=['col1','col2']),ignore_index=True)
>>> df
  col1 col2
0    a    b
1    d    e
2    f    g
```

Comment: Does it create a copy? Is it possible to append in-place?

Comment: @lucid_dreamer This creates a copy.

Comment: The `ignore_index` parameter is optional (`False` by default).

Answer (score 22):

There are several ways to append a list to a Pandas Dataframe in Python. Let's consider the following dataframe and list:

```
import pandas as pd
# Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns = ["col1", "col2"])
# List to append
list = [5, 6]
```

**Option 1:** append the list at the end of the dataframe with ﻿`pandas.DataFrame.loc`.

```
df.loc[len(df)] = list
```

**Option 2:** convert the list to dataframe and append with `﻿pandas.DataFrame.append()`.

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([list], columns=df.columns), ignore_index=True)
```

**Option 3:** convert the list to series and append with `﻿﻿pandas.DataFrame.append()﻿`.

```
df = df.append(pd.Series(list, index = df.columns), ignore_index=True)
```

Each of the above options should output something like:

```
>>> print (df)
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     3     4
2     5     6
```

Reference : [How to append a list as a row to a Pandas DataFrame in Python?](https://alphons.io/1873/how-to-append-a-list-as-a-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python/)

Comment: Why `df.loc` in the first option instead of `df.iloc`?

Comment: @DaniloMatrangoloMarano check this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/how-are-iloc-and-loc-different

Comment: best answer available

Answer (score 8):

Converting the list to a data frame within the append function works, also when applied in a loop

```
import pandas as pd
mylist = [1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(data[mylist]))
```

Comment: What is `data[mylist]` ? Obviously, it throws the error `NameError: name 'data' is not defined`.  Five votes show they know?

Comment: correct should be `df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(data=[mylist]))` . It is missing '=' after data.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a function that, given an already created dataframe, will append a list as a new row. This should probably have error catchers thrown in, but if you know exactly what you're adding then it shouldn't be an issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def addRow(df,ls):
    """
    Given a dataframe and a list, append the list as a new row to the dataframe.

    :param df: <DataFrame> The original dataframe
    :param ls: <list> The new row to be added
    :return: <DataFrame> The dataframe with the newly appended row
    """

    numEl = len(ls)

    newRow = pd.DataFrame(np.array(ls).reshape(1,numEl), columns = list(df.columns))

    df = df.append(newRow, ignore_index=True)

    return df
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add a Series and use the Series' index as columns of the DataFrame, you only need to append the Series between brackets:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame()

In [3]: row=pd.Series([1,2,3],["A","B","C"])

In [4]: row
Out[4]: 
A    1
B    2
C    3
dtype: int64

In [5]: df.append([row],ignore_index=True)
Out[5]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3

[1 rows x 3 columns]
```

Whitout the `ignore_index=True` you don't get proper index.

Answer (score 4):

Consider an array A of N x 2 dimensions. To add one more row, use the following.

```
A.loc[A.shape[0]] = [3,4]
```

Comment: you can create code block for code with 3 backticks

Answer (score 3):

simply use loc:

```
>>> df
     A  B  C
one  1  2  3
>>> df.loc["two"] = [4,5,6]
>>> df
     A  B  C
one  1  2  3
two  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned here - https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-append-a-list-as-a-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python, you'll need to first convert the list to a series then append the series to dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns = ["a", "b"])
to_append = [5, 6]
a_series = pd.Series(to_append, index = df.columns)
df = df.append(a_series, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will give an example with pd.concat as df.append is going to get deprecated,
Let's see how to append a list to an empty dataframe(just with column headers)

Create an empty dataframe onto which we will append the list

```
import pandas as pd  
columns=["Col1","Col2"]  
empty_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

[image: empty_df]

Append a list

```
list_to_append = [1,2]
dict_from_list= {k:v for k,v in zip(columns,list_to_append)}
df_for_list = pd.DataFrame(dict_from_list,index=[0])
concatenated_df = pd.concat([empty_df,df_for_list],ignore_index=True)
```

[image: concatenated_df]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
df['new_column'] = pd.Series(my_list).values
```

Edit:

**Don't forget that the length of the new list should be the same of the corresponding Dataframe.**

Comment: this works for a single instance of the list, but if you have multiple occurrences than my version works