# Append series onto dataframe as row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following series and dataframe. I would like to append or concat the transposed series onto the dataframe such that the dataframe only has one row.

Series:

```
No.                                    9
Ticker                              LULU
Company         Lululemon Athletica Inc.
Sector                    Consumer Goods
Industry      Textile - Apparel Clothing
Country                           Canada
Market Cap                        11.87B
P/E                                42.72
Price                              85.96
Change                             9.21%
Volume                          10704010
Name: 8, dtype: object
```

Dataframe:

```
     Ask   Bid  Chg     Expiry        IV  IsNonstandard  Last  \
57  1.05  0.87 -5.0 2018-04-06  0.333014          False  0.85

             Last_Trade_Date  Open_Int     PctChg      ...       \
57  2018-03-28T19:42:27.000Z       8.0 -85.470085      ...

   Underlying_Price Update_Date  Update_Time   Vol  \
57            85.96    20180328     14:56:13  65.0

                                 _id  iteration Start Price Diff from Current  \
57  LULU_20180406_20180328_26_p_84.0         26        0.96         -0.022801

    Closed Current Price
57   False          None

[1 rows x 25 columns]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending a list or series to a pandas DataFrame as a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309962/appending-a-list-or-series-to-a-pandas-dataframe-as-a-row)

Comment: Some code to generate your sample data may be helpful to stimulate an answer?

Comment: I ended up iterating through the series keys and adding them to the end of the dataframe.