# How to append a list to dataframe without using column names?

Tags: python, pandas, append

I want to append a list of four prices `[1, 2, 3, 4]` to an already existing dataframe using the `DataFrame.append()`, the already existing dataframe has four columns.

Using this

```py
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=["open", "high", "low", "close"],
                         data = [[1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Creates the dataframe

```
   open  high  low  close
0     1     2    3      4
```

Then I want to append some lists like this:

```py
dataframe = dataframe.append([[5, 6, 7, 8]],
                             ignore_index =True)
```

Gives the output

```
   open  high  low  close    0    1    2    3
0   1.0   2.0  3.0    4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```

While I want the list to be appended in continuation to the dataframe, is there a way to do this without using the column names, only the list of four prices?

Comment: First, stop and ask yourself *why are you doing this*. You almost never want to append single rows to a dataframe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending a list or series to a pandas DataFrame as a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309962/appending-a-list-or-series-to-a-pandas-dataframe-as-a-row)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I want to do this to convert a time series of tick data into rangebar data, (rangebar are a variant of candlesticks where new candles are only generated when price moves outside a certain range).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga completely wrong. streaming data needs to be added row by row

Comment: @SujayPhadke not by using `pandas.Dataframe.append`, that is a classic antipattern. You should use a list, append to the list, then create the final data frame in one step

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga But the df may need to be updated real time, just like the list. There is no such rule written in stone that "don't append single rows to a df"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like

```
df.loc[len(df)] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: How about if the added row is not complete, `df.loc[len(df)] = [1, 2, 3]` , which would result in size mismatch?

Answer (score 0):

if you will be adding more than one row, you should use the `concat` function. Which will require you to add the new data in a `DataFrame` first.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Read more in the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#concatenating-objects).

Comment: I think OP wants to append a list to a dataframe. Here `pd.concat` will concatenate two dataframes.

Comment: @Prerit I know, I also saw that he said "then I want to append some lists like this", keyword lists.

Comment: Yea, totally missed the "some" word. My bad. He need to convert the list of list to a dataframe and concatenate.

Comment: The output is like the OP one