# Adding data to pandas dataframe with no header

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to add a row(list of int) to pandas dataframe but i am somehow unable to append it. The thing is the dataframe has no header and everywhere the put data through specifying column names. I dont understand how to do it without header. Below is my dataframe named **sheet**

```
sheet = pd.read_csv("labels.csv",header = None) #sheet = [[1,1,1,2,2 ...]]
```

i want to append resulting list named `simple_list = [1,2,3,4,2,1,1,1]` to it.

Comment: What's does the error say? How many columns are in your dataframe? Does this number agree with the number of datapoints in `simple_list`? For example, how does `sheet.head()` look?

Comment: so i have 60000 cells in .csv file in one row.

Comment: It numbers them with indeces 0,1,2,3,....59999 and place points under them

Comment: from what i understood u wanted to add a row to your dataframe?

Comment: @Datanovice the first line says so ... trying to add a row(list of int)

Comment: `pd.concat([sheet,pd.DataFrame({k:v for k,v in zip(sheet.columns.tolist(),simple_list)})])` I thought something like this.Since append will just create a new column?

Comment: Always add further explanation to your posts, not in the comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10715965/11301900, https://stackoverflow.com/q/26309962/11301900

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add one row to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following work?

```
sheet = sheet.append(pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,2,1,1,1]]), ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a series out of `simple_list`.

```
simple_series = pd.Series(simple_list)
```

Then you can append a row to your dataframe with argument `ignore_index=True`:

```
sheet = sheet.append(simple_series, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me. sheet.appends returns a dataframe, you need to assign it to the same var or a new one to us it. If not "sheet" will have always the original CSV content

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sheet = pd.read_csv("labels.csv", header=None)
    sheet = sheet.append([[41, 42, 42, 44, 45]], ignore_index=True)
```