# how do I insert a row for under a specific cell value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe below and I want to insert a new row under shop with values, how do I do that ?

```
values = 0.2, park, false


df1 = 
   number    variable values
1     NaN        bank   True
2     3.0        shop  False
3     0.5      market   True
4     NaN  government   True
5     1.0       hotel   true
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending a list or series to a pandas DataFrame as a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309962/appending-a-list-or-series-to-a-pandas-dataframe-as-a-row)

Comment: I would like it to be added as a row under shop not at the end of the dataframe, variable = shop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'number': [float('NaN'), 3.0, 0.5, float('NaN'), 1.0], 'variable':['bank','shop','market','government','hotel'], 'values':[True, False, True, True, True]})
print("----- ORIGINAL ------")
print(df)
shop_index = df.reset_index()['variable'].tolist().index('shop') 
insert = pd.DataFrame({"number": 0.2, "variable": "park", "values": False}, index=[shop_index+1])

df2 = pd.concat([df.iloc[:shop_index+1], insert, df.iloc[shop_index+1:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
print("----- AFTER INSERT ------")
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
----- ORIGINAL ------
   number    variable  values
0     NaN        bank    True
1     3.0        shop   False
2     0.5      market    True
3     NaN  government    True
4     1.0       hotel    True


----- AFTER INSERT ------
   number    variable  values
0     NaN        bank    True
1     3.0        shop   False
2     0.2        park   False
3     0.5      market    True
4     NaN  government    True
5     1.0       hotel    True
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I put this into a loop, so I can add shop to a much larger dataframe, this was just an example.

Comment: you can add for/while loop.
If answer is correct, please accept the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using indices, you can specify a row to modify using `df.loc[]`
To input

To append to the last row in the current dataframe, get the last index using `df.loc[-1]`, add a new index and sort them.

In your case:

```
df.loc[-1] = values
df.index = df.index + 1 
df = df.sort_index()
```

Comment: I want to insert a row below a specific value in this case where variable = shop