# extract value from span

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

I want to extract a snow depth value from a weather site to a dataframe. (https://www.yr.no/nb/sn%C3%B8dybder/NO-46/Norge/Vestland) Specifically the snow depth for the Jordalen - Nåsen area.
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhkkk.png)

The closest I've gotten is printing all the values using this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

r=requests.get('https://www.yr.no/nb/sn%C3%B8dybder/NO-46/Norge/Vestland')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser') 

result=soup.find_all("span", {"class": "snow-depth__value"})

print(result)
```

But, i've been unsuccessful in figuring a way to transfer this specific value to a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Please see my update about the fact that this will flatten a n `Nx3` matrix of int into a 1D collection of int.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in bs4, I think the actual parameter in `find_all` is called `class_` due to `class` being special reserved word in python. I did take the liberty of actually construucting a 2d table like the one on the page there:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import ResultSet,Tag
import requests
from requests.models import Response
from typing import Generator,List
from pandas import DataFrame

type LazyRow = Generator[str,None,None]
type LazyRowTable = Generator[LazyRow,None,None]

response: Response = requests.get('https://www.yr.no/nb/sn%C3%B8dybder/NO-46/Norge/Vestland')
html: str = response.content
soup: BeautifulSoup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
table_headers: ResultSet = soup.find_all('th',class_='fluid-table__cell--heading')
table_rows: ResultSet = soup.find_all('tr',class_='fluid-table__row fluid-table__row--link')
# columns 1-3 contain short-term data and column 5 (last column) contains cumulative data 
# (I think, I can't read norwegian)
colnames: List[str] = [th.text for th in table_headers]
# parenthesis instead of square brace makes a Generator comprehension
row_data: LazyRowTable = ((child.text for child in row.children) for row in table_rows)

df: DataFrame = DataFrame(row_data,columns = colnames)
df.astype(int,errors='ignore')
```

**UPDATE:**

Code completely refactored based on comments and the fact that this is a 2d table and not a 1d list.

Comment: First of all. Thank you for taking your time to answer my question. It is much appriciated. Your method works, and I was able to print it out as a dataframe, and based on its position in the column, i could extract the value that I am interested in. However, if a snow depth value is not yet reported the value is stated as <span>-</span> instead of <span class="snow-depth__value">25</span>. Hence the number of values in my list changes and the position of my value changes with it. Is there a way to also include the "-" so the order of the list don't change?

Comment: Upon reviewing their page and inspecting the document, It looks like this span will always be the first child of a `<span class="fluid-table__cell-content">`, so you could probably select that and then pull the inner text out of its first child.

Comment: Made some major updates to my example based on this discussion.

Comment: D`: I fixed it to load the entire table directly into a dataframe with the exact same shape

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. I was able to make a program tracking the snowdepth and snowfall on my favorite mountains to monitor conditions and avalanche risk because of your input. Much much appriciated.

Comment: Glad I could help make your back country expeditions a little safer. If I ever end up riding in Norway I'll surely come back to these comments and ask which mountains to visit.

Comment: I’d be happy to :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `string` variable to find the inner content of a HTML node. See: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16836626/11419075)

Like this:

```py
result=[]
for i in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "snow-depth__value"}):
    result.append(i.string)

# or inline

result = [i.string for i in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "snow-depth__value"})]
```

With this you have a list you can than write into a dataframe. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35509134/11419075)

```py
df=pd.DataFrame(result,columns=['Show'])
```

Comment: you can also use the `text` attribute of `bs4.element.Tag` which is the class of the elements in the `bs4.element.ResultSet` returned by `find_all`

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven I see your point, using `text` is cleaner compared to `string`