Adding Lists to DataFrame as rows
I have a program that calls yfinance to get some stock data for a list of ticker symbols. I use ThreadPoolExecutor to process the yfinance call and a list of data is returned for each ticker.
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import yfinance as yf
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd

def get_stats(ticker):
    info = yf.Tickers(ticker).tickers[ticker].info
    data = [ticker, info['volume']/info['floatShares'], info['floatShares']]
    return data

ticker_list = sys.argv[1:]
ticker_list = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'GOOG']
ticker_list = [item.upper() for item in ticker_list]

table_title = ['Symbol', 'FTR', 'Float']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = table_title)

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = list(executor.map(get_stats, ticker_list))
    df.loc[len(df)] = results

print(df)

When I execute the above code I get the following output:
                                      Symbol                                       FTR                                       Float
0  [AAPL, 0.003960062654206358, 15179506298]  [AMZN, 0.006952834770567285, 9360261411]  [GOOG, 0.0029524428963116282, 10942799280]

Checking the suggestion found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48440126/21926611 I'm not sure why I get the above output instead of the desired output
   Symbol FTR                   Float
0  AAPL   0.003960062654206358  15179506298
1  AMZN   0.006952834770567285  9360261411
2  GOOG   0.0029524428963116282 10942799280


Your code adds the entire results list to each row. You'll want to add each individual item from results list instead.
import sys
import yfinance as yf
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd

def get_stats(ticker):
    info = yf.Tickers(ticker).tickers[ticker].info
    data = [ticker, info['volume']/info['floatShares'], info['floatShares']]
    return data

ticker_list = sys.argv[1:]
ticker_list = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'GOOG']
ticker_list = [item.upper() for item in ticker_list]

table_title = ['Symbol', 'FTR', 'Float']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = table_title)

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = list(executor.map(get_stats, ticker_list))
    # Adds items from results
    for result in results:
      df.loc[len(df)] = result

print(df)


Thank you. That solved it. I'm telling you, I'm having the hardest time to grasp dataframe processing.
