# Why can't I append pandas dataframe in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know that there are several ways to build up a dataframe in Pandas.  My question is simply to understand why the method below doesn't work.

First, a working example.  I can create an empty dataframe and then append a new one similar to the documenta

```
In [3]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],], columns = ['a', 'b'])
   ...: df2 = pd.DataFrame()    
   ...: df2.append(df1)
```

`Out[3]:   a  b
        0  1  2`

However, if I do the following df2 becomes None:

```
In [10]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],], columns = ['a', 'b'])
    ...: df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    ...: for i in range(10):
    ...:     df2.append(df1)

In [11]: df2
Out[11]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Can someone explain why it works this way? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/37009377/3639023

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This happens because the .append() method returns a new df:

> [Pandas Docs (0.19.2)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):
>
> pandas.DataFrame.append
>
> **Returns:**  **appended:** *DataFrame*

Here's a working example so you can see what's happening in each iteration of the loop:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],], columns=['a','b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,2):
    print(df2.append(df1))

>    a  b
> 0  1  2
>    a  b
> 0  1  2
```

If you assign the output of .append() to a df (even the same one) you'll get what you probably expected:

```
for i in range(0,2):
    df2 = df2.append(df1)
print(df2)

>    a  b
> 0  1  2
> 0  1  2
```

Comment: Excellent response!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],], columns=['a','b','c'])


for i in range(0,4):
    df1 = df1.append(df2)

df1
```

Comment: It will be great to see some explanation of your logic.

Answer (score 0):

df.append() returns a new object. df2 is a empty dataframe initially, and it will not change.  if u do a df3=df2.append(df1), u will get what u want