# Iterate through Dataframe Rows in Loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have rows of links contained in a dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

I need to iterate over the rows of links in the dataframe one at a time so I can perform selenium tasks on each link separately. It should iterate over these rows in a loop until there are no more rows in the dataframe.

```
     links
0    http://linkone
0    http://linktwo
0    http://linkthree
```

My logic is as follows

```
Loop
    Get http://linkone in first row of dataframe
    Use selenium to perform tasks, such as driver.get(http://linkone)
    Gather data from HTML from http://linkone

    Continue loop and get row 2, row 3, etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you dont need `iterrows()`, just use a `for` loop.

Simply use a for loop:

```
for link in df.links:
    print(link)
    print('do something with selenium')

http://linkone
do something with selenium
http://linktwo
do something with selenium
http://linkthree
do something with selenium
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. That was simple enough!

Comment: No problem, happy coding!