# Concat databases and update duplicate rows

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

My problem is : I have multiple identical databases and I want to merge them into one. But I may have duplicate entries as Primary Keys. What i'm trying to do is handle the duplicates before putting them in Mysql.

my actual code is:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame() 
duplicates = pd.DataFrame()
size=[]
lignes=[]
chunksize = 100000


for db in dbtuple: #For each databases in the tuple given as entry
    engine = create_engine(URL(
            drivername="mysql",
            username="xxx",
            password="xxx",
            host="localhost",
            database=db
        ))
    conn = engine.connect()
    #Get the data from the table given as entry
    sql = "SELECT * FROM "+ tableName

    #Execution of the query above
    generator_df = pd.read_sql(sql=sql,con=conn,chunksize= chunksize)

    #Init of sizechunk value
    sizechunk = 0

    #Because the query can be very big number of rows there's a separation
    # every 100k rows so that dataframe size <= 100k 
    for dataframe in generator_df:
        df = pd.concat([df,dataframe],ignore_index = True, axis=0,sort=False)

        #We add the size of the chunk to know how many rows we have per database
        sizechunk+= dataframe.shape[0]

        size.append(sizechunk)


    if tableName == 'table1':
        duplicates = df.duplicated(subset='id')

        for i in range(0,len(df)):
            if duplicates[i]:

                df.id[i] = numligne + '_' + df.id[i]
    #same for all tables
```

But this is not pythonic way at all and is it very long to execute. Do you have any suggestion on how to improve the code to make it faster ?

Here is my db schema to understand better:

````
table1 = Table('table1', metadata,
    Column('id', VARCHAR(40), primary_key=True,nullable=False),
    mysql_engine='InnoDB'
    )

table2= Table('table2', metadata,
    Column('id', VARCHAR(40), primary_key=True,nullable=False),
    Column('id_of', VARCHAR(20),ForeignKey("table1.id"), nullable=False, index= True)
    )

table3= Table('table3', metadata,
    Column('index',BIGINT(10), primary_key=True,nullable=False,autoincrement=True),
    Column('id', VARCHAR(40),nullable=False),
    Column('id_produit', VARCHAR(40),ForeignKey("table2.id"), nullable=False, index= True),
    Column('id_produit_enfant', VARCHAR(40),ForeignKey("table2.id"), nullable=False, index= True)
    )

table4= Table('table4', metadata,
    Column('index',BIGINT(10), primary_key=True,nullable=False,autoincrement=True),
    Column('id', VARCHAR(40),nullable=False),
    Column('id_produit', VARCHAR(40),ForeignKey("table2.id"), nullable=False, index= True)
    )

table5= Table('table5', metadata,
    Column('index',BIGINT(10), primary_key=True,nullable=False,autoincrement=True),
    Column('id', VARCHAR(40),nullable=False),
    Column('id_produit', VARCHAR(40),ForeignKey("table2.id"), nullable=False, index= True)
    )

table6= Table('table6', metadata,
    Column('index',BIGINT(10), primary_key=True,nullable=False,autoincrement=True),
    Column('id', VARCHAR(40),nullable=False),
    Column('id_produit', VARCHAR(40),ForeignKey("table2.id"), nullable=False, index= True)
    )```
````

Comment: please look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37009561/9754169

Comment: I'm not using append but concat for the dataframe

Comment: I know, but you could test the proposed idea, save the chunks in a list and then append it with concat

Comment: So you think that putting my dataframe inside lists and then work with lists and put it back in dataframe is better ?

Comment: I think putting chunks in a list and then use concat once is better, yes

Comment: And do you think check for duplicates is better with lists or dataframes ?

Comment: check for dups over the full dataframe using `pd.DataFrame.duplicated()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193697/discussion-between-hanggy-and-yuca).