# With pandas filter rows on sum of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to select rows in a dataframe based on a sum crieteria of one of the columns. For example I want the indexes of the the first rows of the dataframe where the sum of column B is less than 3:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[z, y, x, w], 'B':[1, 1, 1, 1]})
```

The only solution I have is a seperate dataframe and a while loop:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[], 'B':[]})
index = 0
while df2['B'].sum() < 3:
    df2 = df2.append(df1.loc[index])
    index += 1
```

The logic gets me where I need but seems unnecessarily inefficient. Does anyone have a creative way of using pandas to filter the dataframe based on sum conditional of a column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is a cumulative sum ([`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)).

Appending rows to a DataFrame within a loop is [horribly inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37009561/4333359) as it copies the entire DataFrame on every iteration just to append an additional small amount of data. Instead you should look to slice your original DataFrame with a Boolean mask; in this case checking where the `cumsum` is less than 3.

```
df2 = df[df['B'].cumsum().lt(3)]

#   A  B
#0  z  1
#1  y  1
```

---

```
df['B'].cumsum()
#0    1
#1    2
#2    3
#3    4

df['B'].cumsum().lt(3)
#0     True     <- Slicing with this Boolean Series
#1     True     <- keeps only these True rows
#2    False
#3    False
```

Comment: Freaking fantastic and exactly what I was looking for. I felt the inefficiency in my chest but couldn't come up with a way to slice my way home. Thank you!

Comment: short follow up question. How would I add the next row. Say this represented physical goods and I wanted some buffer in my stock and in the same scenario the value for B was 2 but I wanted to include it anyway because I had a 50% margin. Here is where the while loop was nice and I don't see a  one-line slicing solution to add the extra row

Comment: @chic9009 oh that's a good question. I won't be able to answer that right now but I'll follow up in an hour or two when I have some free time.