# How to efficiently change a piece of code from the append method using the concat() method?

Tags: pandas, append, concatenation

I am a beginner in python and need help with the concat() method as the **append** method has been deprecated. Could anyone show me how to use the concat() method for this code? thanks

```
def gettrigger(self):
    dfx = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(self.lags + 1):
        mask = (self.df['%K'].shift(i) < 20) & (self.df['%D'].shift(i) < 20)
        dfx = dfx.append(mask, ignore_index=True)
    return dfx.sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: this question and answers to it might help you!
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009287/using-pandas-append-within-for-loop>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
dfx = pd.concat([(self.df['%K'].shift(i) < 20) & (self.df['%D'].shift(i) < 20) for i in range(self.lags + 1)],
                ignore_index=True)
```

The list comprehension will create a list of objects to concatenate.