# Appending data is inturrepted by incomplete data , error of "cannot set a row with mismatched columns"

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-analysis

While scraping data and appending to a data frame through a function using python. The append fuction is inturrepted due to the mismatch in the declared data frame and the missing data in the columns of the data that i scraped.Some i am unable to collect rest of the clean. Is ther any way we can skip the excution of incomplete data while parsing. Can someone suggest how can i get around this and append the rest of data. Any suggestions on how to handle this problem while parcing the Html data.

Sample data looks something like this...

Country (or dependent territory)    2020    2021    2022    2023
Afghanistan           20,136   14,941                 19,083   23,032
Albania           15,192   17,984
Algeria          145,656   163,138               195,060   224,107

I have declared the dataframe properly and then used the following to append the data.
GDP_2020 is the saved html data.

```
       years=['2020','2021','2022','2023']
       GDP=pd.DataFrame(columns=years)        
       for row in GDP_2020[1:]:
           row_data=row.find_all('td')
           individual_row_data=[data.text.strip() for data in row_data]    
           length=len(GDP)
           GDP.loc[length]=individual_row_data
```

The above code is saving the data of the first but the function gets inturrepted by the next line as you can see it is incomplete...and returns 'cannot set a row with mismatched columns'....any suggestions?

Comment: You could check the length of `individual_row_data` ; filling the row of dataframe only if the length is equal to 4

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can approach this:

1. Skip the data if we don't have data for all 4 years
2. Add `np.nan` to the rows where the data is not available

**Approach 1**

```
years = ['2020','2021','2022','2023']
row_data = []      
for row in GDP_2020[1:]:
    row_data = row.find_all('td')
    individual_row_data = [data.text.strip() for data in row_data]
    if len(individual_row_data) == 4:
        row_data.append(individual_row_data)

GDP = pd.DataFrame(row_data, columns=years)
```

**Approach 2**

```
years = ['2020','2021','2022','2023']
col_len = len(years)
row_data = []      
for row in GDP_2020[1:]:
    row_data = row.find_all('td')
    individual_row_data = [data.text.strip() for data in row_data]
    row_data.append(individual_row_data + [np.nan] * (col_len - len(individual_row_data)))

GDP = pd.DataFrame(row_data, columns=years)
```

Also if you notice, I'm using list to store all the row data first and then create the dataframe at the end. This is more efficient than adding a row multiple time to dataframe in a loop ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009287/using-pandas-append-within-for-loop))

One more thing, approach 2 assumes that the missing data would be from later years and be consecutive i.e., say we have data from 2020, 2021 but missing data from 2022 and 2023. Unless I see how the data comes where the missing data is in between two years example data present for 2020 & 2022; missing for 2021 and 2023, I cannot judge how to handle that scenario.

Comment: I intend to pursue the approach 2. But the approach is giving the error of "Shape of passed values is (11, 1), indices imply (11, 11)". Column length is 11 and 1 suggests the last row the iteration. Somehow the appending is not taking place while i understood the logic you suggested. Suggest what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Can you show what you are getting in the `row_data` during the error scenario?