# Reading multiple csv file with specificing character in naming

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-3.7

I have multiple csv file in a folder and some of them end with 'xxxxx.t01.csv'. Now what I want to do is to create a list of data frames in panda which contains all these files with '.t01.csv' ending. I tried to use fnmatch and globe2 but none of them worked. (I use python 3.7). Here are my codes:

```
import os, fnmatch
import pandas as pd

list_of_files = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\My_PC\\Desktop\\new folder')   
for entry in list_of_files:  
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, '*t01.csv'):
       df=pd.read_csv(entry)

       print(df[])
```

and I got this error:

[image]

then I tried with glob2 as well but I got nowhere.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob2

path = r''C:\\Users\\My_PC\\Desktop\\new folder''
all_files = glob2.glob(path + "*t01.csv")


for filename in all_files:

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    print(df)
```

but it will show nothing. Could someone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: You have to append the base path with the file name. `all_files` contains the filename in string format and not actual file objects.

Comment: @mad_ thanks for your quick reply but i just append the base path but nothing happend. I guess somthing wrong with logic of my code ????!! what do you think

Comment: refer to below posted answers

Comment: the path is  correct,  because when i  deactivate the line ´ df=pd.read_csv(entry)´  in fnmatch part, it should a list of the names correctly but i keep constantly get this mentioend error or error with encoding (i use windows)

Comment: Then I will point you to have a look at documentation before moving forward https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html. There is `encoding` parameter that can be useful

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.chdir()` and `glob`:

```
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\My_PC\\Desktop\\new folder\\')
all_files = glob.glob("*t01.csv")

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    print(df)
    print("---------seperator--------------")
```

For appending them together in one dataframe: [refer to this lnk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669482/appending-pandas-dataframes-generated-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory that it is unable to find the filename in the current directory. To resolve the issue pass in the complete filepath or change the current working directory using `os.chdir(path)` which is not recommended. Replace filename as below using [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

```
pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,filename), index_col=None, header=0)
```