# How to Import Multiple excel file in PandasDataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx

I cannot load multiple excel files from a directory in only one Dataframe.
I have tried two different ways and both do no work.

Gives me this error.

How can I solve the problem? It does find the files when creates the list, but than cannot open it in the Dataframe.
Any hints ?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import xlrd

cwd = os.getcwd()
cwd

path = '/Users/giovanni/Desktop/news media'
files = os.listdir(path)
files


files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'lsx']
files_xls





df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files_xls:
    data = pd.read_excel(f)
    df = df.append(data)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'NOV.xlsx'
```

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: You need to provide a little bit more information: Are all the excel files in the same format? (ie same sheet name with data, same columns).

Comment: check this, it serves your purpose better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669482/appending-pandas-dataframes-generated-in-a-for-loop

Comment: I am using MAC. All the files are in the same format

It does find all the list in the directory, so when run files_xls all the names appear as output, but than gives me this error

Comment: Please Change Spelling of your file Extention, which should be 'xls', not 'lsx'

Comment: @Nidal all the excel files in the same format, same sheet name with same data and same columns

Comment: @Ghanshyam that's only to find the list of files that I wanna upload

Comment: @jonny Bravo, There should be path = os.getcwd() and then run the code(Make sure that all your required file available in your cwd), currently, the code is searching your file in the default directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
import glob
path = '/Users/giovanni/Desktop/news media'
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.xlsx')):
    data = pd.read_excel(file)
    print(data)
    df = df.append(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your final loop with:

```
for f in files_xls:
    full_path = os.path.join(path, f)
    data = pd.read_excel(full_path) 
    df = df.append(data)
```