# Combine Dataframes at end of a loop for Web Page scrape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have started to write a programme to Web scrape a table of data from a number of URLs. I have got to the point where I create a list of urls from importing an Excel spreadsheet, loop through the url list and scrape a specific table on the webpage by searching for the table header.

The print statement at the end of the loop prints out the separate table for each url individually. Is there an easy way I can append() the DataFrame rows together similar to an easy list generation? The tables are the same layouts.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re
import ssl
import lxml
import xlrd
import csv

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

#auto import excel file
ex = pd.read_excel(r'/Users/adamsewell/Desktop/GB_Basketball/Data/GB_Player_Tracking_Document.xlsm', sheet_name='Player URL')
yr = '2019-20'

#list urls from excel sheet
url_list = ex['URL'].tolist()

for url in url_list:
    #first header as a reference point
    table_title = 'International Regular Season Stats - Per Game'
    #replace to gain second header title to end loop
    second_header = (table_title.replace(' Per Game',' Totals'))

    html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    #find the table in the whole HTML
    start = soup.find('h2', text=table_title)
    end = soup.find('h2', text=second_header)
    content = '' #prime content as nothing
    item = start.nextSibling

    #while not at the end header, add content to the item
    while item != end:
        content += str(item)
        item = item.nextSibling

    #create a list and concat to a dataframe table
    dfs = pd.read_html(content)
    df = pd.concat(dfs)

    #remove unwanted row (if not year of interest)
    indexNames = df[(df['Season'] != yr) & (df['Season'] != yr + ' *')].index
    df.drop(indexNames, inplace=True)

    #abstract players name from GM URL
    name_split = url.split('/')
    players_name = (name_split[4].replace('-', ' '))

    #Add column of player name, add player name from URL, and move to first column
    df['Player Name'] = players_name
    col_name = 'Player Name'
    first_col = df.pop(col_name)
    df.head
    df.insert(0,'Player Name', first_col)
    print(df)
```

I am really new to programming and have only started using python about 3 weeks ago so the simpler the answer the better! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done bit more digging an found the a solution on a previous answer on the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669482/appending-pandas-dataframes-generated-in-a-for-loop)

```
#set new df 
real_gm_append = []

for url in url_list:
........................

    #append to new data frame
    real_gm_append.append(df)

real_gm_append = pd.concat(real_gm_append)
print(real_gm_append)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the requirement, you just want to merge all the dataframe to a single dataframe.

Try this code:

```
dfFull = None
for url in url_list:
    .........
    print(df)
    if dfFull == None: 
        dfFull = df  # start with first set
    else:  # append new df
        dfFull.append(df, ignore_index=True) 

print(dfFull)
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for the code. Unfortunately it returns a trace back error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Real_GM_v2.py", line 65, in <module>
    if dfFull == None:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1326, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`               Would I maybe append it to a list (a.item()) and then concat the list back to a DataFrame maybe?