# Python Pandas - filter pandas dataframe to get rows with minimum values in one column for each unique value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Here is a dummy example of the DF I'm working with ('ETC' represents several columns):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'PlotCode':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C'],
                        'INVYR':[2000,2000,2000,2005,1990,2000,1990,2005,2001],
                        'ETC':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']})
```

[picture of df (sorry not enough reputation yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vMIY.png)

And here is what I want to end up with:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'PlotCode':['A','A','A','B','B','C'],
                        'INVYR':[2000,2000,2000,1990,1990,2001],
                        'ETC':['a','b','c','e','g','i']})
```

[picture of df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ljAT.png)

NOTE: I want **ALL** rows with minimum 'INVYR' values for each 'PlotCode', not just one or else I'm assuming I could do something easier with drop_duplicates and sort.

So far, following the answer here [Appending pandas dataframes generated in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669482/appending-pandas-dataframes-generated-in-a-for-loop) I've tried this with the following code:

```
df1 = []

for i in df['PlotCode'].unique():
    j = df[df['PlotCode']==i]
    k = j[j['INVYR']==j['INVYR'].min()]
    df1.append(k)

df1 = pd.concat(df1)
```

This code works but is very slow, my actual data contains some 40,000 different PlotCodes so this isn't a feasible solution. Does anyone know some smooth filtering way of doing this? I feel like I'm missing something very simple.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `df.groupby(['PlotCode']).apply(lambda x: x[x.INVYR==x.INVYR.min()]).reset_index(drop=True)` -- I though this would be faster - but it's somehow slower (at least on a very small dataset, maybe it'll be faster on a larger one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to use for loops when using pandas, they are extremely slow in comparison to the vectorized operations that pandas has.

**Solution 1:**
Determine the minimum INVYR for every plotcode, using [.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
min_invyr_per_plotcode = df.groupby('PlotCode', as_index=False)['INVYR'].min()
```

And use [pd.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to do an inner join between your orignal df with this minimum you just found:

```
result_df = pd.merge(
    df, 
    min_invyr_per_plotcode, 
    how='inner', 
    on=['PlotCode', 'INVYR'],
)
```

**Solution 2:**

Again, determine the minimum per group, but now add it as a column to your dataframe. This minimum per group gets added to every row by using [.groupby().transform()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html)

```
df['min_per_group'] = (df
    .groupby('PlotCode')['INVYR']
    .transform('min')
)
```

Now filter your dataframe where INVYR in a row is equal to the minimum of that group:

```
df[df['INVYR'] == df['min_per_group']]
```

Comment: Amazing! Knew there had to be a better vectorized way but couldn't quite work it out. Thank you so much!