# How to increase efficiency of binning and filtering of pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

### Problem/Question

I like to filter/reduce trajectory data, only keeping first occurrences per a given square size.

Below I have an example which kind of works but is too slow for the data size I am looking at (~100_000 id's and much more time steps).

So my question is how to do this efficiently and maybe somewhat shorter and cleaner?

### Code example

In this example, only one row will be dropped by the filter (see very last step, index "1"). Also the formatting of the final result is... awkward.

#### Generating dummy data

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def time(t):
    return pd.Timestamp("2019-01-01T12") + pd.to_timedelta(t, "d")


arrays = [
    np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]),
    np.array([time(0), time(1), time(396), time(365), time(31), time(365)]),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1.1,0.9,2.1,3.2,5.5,4.5],[1.2,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.5,5.5]]).T, index=arrays, columns=["lon", "lat"])
df.index.names = ["id", "time"]
df
```

returns

```
        lon     lat
id  time        
1   2019-01-01 12:00:00     1.1     1.2
    2019-01-02 12:00:00     0.9     1.0
2   2020-02-01 12:00:00     2.1     2.0
    2020-01-01 12:00:00     3.2     3.0
3   2019-02-01 12:00:00     5.5     4.5
    2020-01-01 12:00:00     4.5     5.5
```

#### Prepare binning

```py
df = df.assign(lonbin=np.round(df.lon, decimals=0))
df = df.assign(latbin=np.round(df.lat, decimals=0))
df
```

returns

```
        lon     lat     lonbin  latbin
id  time                
1   2019-01-01 12:00:00     1.1     1.2     1.0     1.0
    2019-01-02 12:00:00     0.9     1.0     1.0     1.0
2   2020-02-01 12:00:00     2.1     2.0     2.0     2.0
    2020-01-01 12:00:00     3.2     3.0     3.0     3.0
3   2019-02-01 12:00:00     5.5     4.5     6.0     4.0
    2020-01-01 12:00:00     4.5     5.5     4.0     6.0
```

#### Filtering for first occurrence of lat-lon combination

```py
x = pd.DataFrame()
for idx in set(df.index.get_level_values("id")):
    x = pd.concat(
        [
            x,
            (
                df.query(f"id == '{idx}'")
                .groupby(["lonbin", "latbin"])
                .idxmin()
                .reset_index()
                .assign(id=idx)
                .set_index("id")
            ),
        ]
    )
x
```

returns

```
    lonbin  latbin  lon     lat
id              
1   1.0     1.0     (1, 2019-01-02 12:00:00)    (1, 2019-01-02 12:00:00)
2   2.0     2.0     (2, 2020-02-01 12:00:00)    (2, 2020-02-01 12:00:00)
2   3.0     3.0     (2, 2020-01-01 12:00:00)    (2, 2020-01-01 12:00:00)
3   4.0     6.0     (3, 2020-01-01 12:00:00)    (3, 2020-01-01 12:00:00)
3   6.0     4.0     (3, 2019-02-01 12:00:00)    (3, 2019-02-01 12:00:00)
```

with (e.g.) `sns.jointplot(x=x.lonbin, y=x.latbin, kind="hex")` I could then look at a binned plot (or maybe calculating densities with `scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde`).

Comment: you don't need the loop and the concat, your output can be obtained directly with `x = df.groupby(['id', "lonbin", "latbin"]).idxmin().reset_index(level=["lonbin", "latbin"])`, definitely faster than using concat in each loop

Comment: Repeated concat is slow, use concat once at the end of a loop instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28670223/530160

Comment: if I had another column, with some data like `Age`, how could I calculate for example an average in the constraints of the binning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comment by @Ben.T using `groupby` with the other two columns simplifies the code and the speed will just be determined by `groupby`, i.e.

```py
x = (
    df.groupby(["id", "lonbin", "latbin"])
    .idxmin()
    .reset_index(level=["lonbin", "latbin"])
)
```