# Pandas/Python append or concat dataframes being created in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a process which I am able to loop through for values held in a list but it overwrites the final dataframe with each
loop and I would like to append or concat the result of the loops into one dataframe.
For example given below I can see 'dataframe' will populate initially with result of 'blah1', then when process finishes it has the result of 'blah2'

```
listtoloop = ['blah1','blah2']

for name in listtoloop:


    some process happens here resulting in

        dataframe = result of above process
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669482/appending-pandas-dataframes-generated-in-a-for-loop

Answer (score 7):

The typical pattern used for this is to create a list of DataFrames, and only at the end of the loop, concatenate them into a single DataFrame. This is usually much faster than appending new rows to the DataFrame after each step, as you are not constructing a new DataFrame on every iteration.

Something like this should work:

```
listtoloop = ['blah1','blah2']
dfs = []
for name in listtoloop:
    # some process happens here resulting in
    # dataframe = result of above process
    dfs.append(dataframe)
final = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I managed to find another way similar, have also posted.

Comment: @Evan that is what thesilkworm gave in their answer here.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned I had found a similar way and posted the link to that way also. Thankyou both, I was continuing to research after I asked and our paths crossed.

Answer (score 0):

Put your results in a list and then append the list to the df making sure the list is in the same order as the df

```
listtoloop = ['blah1','blah2']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns="A","B")
for name in listtoloop:
    ## processes here

    to_append = [5, 6]
    df_length = len(df)
    df.loc[df_length] = to_append
```

Comment: Thankyou, I think I managed to find another way also, posted in answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
data_you_need=pd.DataFrame()  
listtoloop = ['blah1','blah2']  
for name in listtoloop:     
    ##some process happens here resulting in          
    ##dataframe = result of above process    
    data_you_need=data_you_need.append(dataframe,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: The potential issue with this one is it results in a FutureWarning message. frame.append is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. However, you can append to a list no problem. Additionally, it's less performant.